# Concatenating two std::vectors

Tags: c++, stl, concatenation, stdvector

How do I concatenate two `std::vector`s?

Comment: The answers given don't actually concatenate. They append a copy. There may be a use (for efficiency's point of view) to create a std::vector concatenate method, however it would require some sophisticated sharing of the management of the nodes and that's probably why it hasn't been done.

Comment: @FauChristian: No, there may not be a use from an efficiency's point of view. Vector memory must be continuous, so what you are suggested is impossible. If you wanted "some sophisticated sharing of the management of the nodes", and if you were to change the vector class in such a way, you would end up with a deque. Even then it is very difficult to reuse memory in the way suggested, albeit it would start being a bit more feasible. I don't think it is currently implemented. The main thing is that in such a sharing of management nodes (a deque) the end node might be partially empty.

Comment: Am I the only one wondering why this is not implemented as `a + b` or `a.concat(b)` in the standard library? Maybe the default implementation would be suboptimal, but every array concatenation does not need to be micro-optimized

Comment: years of evolution, the most advanced operator-overloading of any mainstream language, a templating system that doubles the complexity of the language, and yet the answer is not v = v1 + v2;

Comment: My guess is the STL didn't want to over-specify the language in case you wanted the operator to do something different, say adding force vectors in a physics model. In that case you might want to overload `forceVector1 + forceVector2` to do itemwise addition in clear, concise code.

Comment: @Spike0xff, v = v1 + v2 has a meaning in math that's not concatenating. It has some requirements too in order to be computable. I would rather suggest an append method (shortcut of what can be done using ```insert```) or a push back overload.

Comment: https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/  the referense on `insert()` might be helpful

Answer (score 1036):

```
vector1.insert( vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end() );
```

Comment: I'd only add code to first get the number of elements each vector holds, and set vector1 to be the one holding the greatest. Should you do otherwise you're doing a lot of unnecessary copying.

Comment: I have a question. Will this work if vector1 and vector2 are the same vectors?

Comment: If you have concatenating several vectors to one, is it helpful to call `reserve` on the destination vector first?

Comment: @AlexanderRafferty: Only if `vector1.capacity() >= 2 * vector1.size()`.  Which is atypical unless you've called `std::vector::reserve()`.  Otherwise the vector will reallocate, invalidating the iterators passed as parameters 2 and 3.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Since arguments of `insert` are vectors, it's already know how many elements are ahead and will handle it itself. If we were inserting other things like array, it was useful to reserve the space first.

Comment: @Khaur: That's horrifying to the point it's hard to believe.  It's super trivial for an implementation to detect the iterators are random access, calculate the size, and pre-reserve the needed space.  I think MSFT's even does that for forward iterators.

Comment: @MooingDuck You're right, I missed the dispatcher and thought the input iterator version applied for all types of iterators. The forward iterator version does a lot more stuff. Thanks for pointing it out, I deleted my initial comment so that it doesn't show up without yours.

Comment: It's too bad there isn't a more succinct expression in the standard library. `.concat` or `+=` or something

Comment: @nmr In C++, this is _quite_ succinct.

Comment: It's hard to get an overview of all the different answers to this question. The `std::vector::insert` approach has been posted in several other answers as well, but this one has most upvotes, so I'll ask/state here: Using `insert` should have an advantage over other approaches which use `back_inserter` because `insert` could potentially memcpy in one bulk while the approaches that use `back_inserter` must iterate over the vector to be inserted element by element. Do I see this right?

Answer (score 308):

If you are using C++11,  and wish to move the elements rather than merely copying them, you can use [`std::move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) along with insert (or copy):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<int> dest{1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<int> src{6,7,8,9,10};

  // Move elements from src to dest.
  // src is left in undefined but safe-to-destruct state.
  dest.insert(
      dest.end(),
      std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()),
      std::make_move_iterator(src.end())
    );

  // Print out concatenated vector.
  std::copy(
      dest.begin(),
      dest.end(),
      std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n")
    );

  return 0;
}
```

This will not be more efficient for the example with ints, since moving them is no more efficient than copying them, but for a data structure with optimized moves, it can avoid copying unnecessary state:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> dest{{1,2,3,4,5}, {3,4}};
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> src{{6,7,8,9,10}};

  // Move elements from src to dest.
  // src is left in undefined but safe-to-destruct state.
  dest.insert(
      dest.end(),
      std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()),
      std::make_move_iterator(src.end())
    );

  return 0;
}
```

After the move, src's element is left in an undefined but safe-to-destruct state, and its former elements were transfered directly to dest's new element at the end.

Comment: The std::make_move_iterator() method helped me when trying to concatenate std::vectors of std::unique_ptr.

Comment: What's the difference between this and `std::move(src.begin(), src.end(), back_inserter(dest))`?

Comment: @kshenoy, `insert` might allocate necessary amount of memory in one turn. When `back_inserter` might lead to several reallocations

Comment: what's the difference between this and not having `std::make_move_iterator()` ?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom This will use the move-constructor to move elements from src to dest. Without std::make_move_iterator it will use the copy-constructor.

Answer (score 190):

I would use the [insert function](http://cppreference.com/wiki/stl/vector/insert), something like:

```
vector<int> a, b;
//fill with data
b.insert(b.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
```

Answer (score 94):

Or you could use:

```
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(destination));
```

This pattern is useful if the two vectors don't contain exactly the same type of thing, because you can use something instead of `std::back_inserter` to convert from one type to the other.

Comment: the copy method is a not such a good way. It will call push_back multiple time which means that if a lot of elements have to be inserted this could mean multiple reallocations. it is better to use insert as the vector implementation could do some optimization to avoid reallocations. it could reserve memory before starting copying

Comment: @Yogesh: granted, but there's nothing stopping you calling `reserve` first. The reason `std::copy` is sometimes useful is if you want to use something other than `back_inserter`.

Comment: When you say "multiple allocations", that is true - but the number of allocations is at worst log(number of entries added) - which means that the cost of adding an entry is constant in the number of entries added.  (Basically, don't worry about it unless profiling shows you need a reserve).

Comment: You might want to use std::transform to do this instead.

Comment: copy sucks a lot, even with reserve. vector::insert will avoid all the checks:
http://quick-bench.com/bLJO4OfkAzMcWia7Pa80ynwmAIA

Comment: @DenisYaroshevskiy  That's a striking difference in performance. Any idea why is that happening? Conceptually, the `using_resize` method writes the memory space of `res` twice, should be the slower one ??

Comment: @SamuelLi - mostly the `if > capacity_` in push_back if a problem.
It's a problem enough that the `memset` in `resize` does not matter.

Answer (score 86):

With C++11, I'd prefer following to append vector b to a:

```
std::move(b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(a));
```

when `a` and `b` are not overlapped, and `b` is not going to be used anymore.

---

This is [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) from `<algorithm>`, not the *usual* [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) from `<utility>`.

Comment: Undefined behaviour if a actually is b (which is OK if you know that can never happen - but worth being aware of in general purpose code).

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks for mentioning that. Probably I should turn back to the old `insert` way which is safer.

Comment: just add following header line the begin:    #include <iterator>

Comment: Ah, the OTHER std::move.   Quite confusing the first time you see it.

Comment: Is this different from `insert()` with `move_iterator`s? If so, how?

Comment: I've added a note about what `std::move` we are talking here, since most people don't know this overload. Hope it's an improvement.

Comment: @Deqing I'm not sure insert is better...  If a is b then as soon as you insert a few elements it will reallocate and invalidate the iterators passed to insert which will then continue to be used, right?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah If a is b, then you cannot use `insert` (it would be undefined behavior). Otherwise, `insert` is preferable, because it can compute the number of elements to insert once in advance.

Answer (score 45):

```
std::vector<int> first;
std::vector<int> second;

first.insert(first.end(), second.begin(), second.end());
```

Answer (score 37):

I prefer one that is already mentioned:

```
a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

But if you use C++11, there is one more generic way:

```
a.insert(std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::end(b));
```

---

Also, not part of a question, but it is advisable to use [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) before appending for better performance. And if you are concatenating vector with itself, without reserving it fails, so you always should `reserve`.

---

So basically what you need:

```
template <typename T>
void Append(std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    a.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
    a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

Comment: `std::` is deduced through [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). `end(a)` will be enough.

Comment: @Asu ADL will only add `std::` if the type of `a` comes from `std`, which defeats the generic aspect.

Comment: good point. in this case it's a vector so it would work anyways, but yes that's a better solution.

Comment: std::begin()/end() were added for collections (like arrays) which don't have them as member functions.  But arrays also don't have an insert() member function, and calls the question  "Is there a collection with an insert() but without begin() (which works with the std::begin()) ?"

Comment: you should prefer not to use reserve, as it might come with a massive overhead. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102335/7110367

Comment: Be warned that using `insert` to concatenate a vector to itself is outside the specification of `insert` (undefined behavior). Calling `reserve` in advance does not change that.

Answer (score 35):

With [range v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), you may have a **lazy** concatenation:

```
ranges::view::concat(v1, v2)
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a323e3792a869244).

Comment: I predict this will be the appropriate answer in 2023 or so.

Comment: @wcochran It's 2023 now. The current C++23 draft (N4928) does not yet contain a concat, but it's in the pipeline to be eventually added to a C++ standard at some point.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica3167040 Bummer -- am also waiting for flying cars. Maybe 2024.

Answer (score 23):

A **general performance boost** for concatenate is to check the size of the vectors. And merge/insert the smaller one with the larger one.

```
//vector<int> v1,v2;
if(v1.size()>v2.size()) {
    v1.insert(v1.end(),v2.begin(),v2.end());
} else {
    v2.insert(v2.end(),v1.begin(),v1.end());
}
```

Comment: So simple, yet I never thought about it that way!

Comment: The sample code is incorrect. `v1.insert(v2.end()...` is using an iterator into `v2` to specify the position in `v1`.

Comment: You can also use a quick swap. @DavidStone I edited it so that the concat order may be changed. Is it possible to add to the beginning of a vector?

Comment: You can insert into the beginning, but that will be slower. To truly "concatenate", however, the order typically does matter, so that is what you need to do.

Comment: I don't like this answer because you don't insert v2 after v1 in all case (without specifying it with a note). Otherwise, your answer could be more complete if you add a solution which save the concatenation in another vector rather than modifiying one of them.

Answer (score 17):

There is an algorithm [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) from **C++17**, which is very easy to use when the input vectors are sorted,

Below is the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    //DATA
    std::vector<int> v1{2,4,6,8};
    std::vector<int> v2{12,14,16,18};

    //MERGE
    std::vector<int> dst;
    std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(dst));

    //PRINT
    for(auto item:dst)
        std::cout<<item<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's any easier to use than `std::vector::insert`, but it does to something different: merging two ranges into a new range vs inserting one vector at the end of another. Worth mentioning in the answer?

Comment: Ok. I understood what is expected in the answer. I will add.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to be able to concatenate vectors concisely, you could overload the `+=` operator.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator +=(std::vector<T>& vector1, const std::vector<T>& vector2) {
    vector1.insert(vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end());
    return vector1;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
vector1 += vector2;
```

Comment: this can be very confusing and is not recommended. `+=` might be perceived as a modification *element-wise*.

Comment: This isn't a good idea because the operator won't be found by ADL, since both arguments are from namespace `std`. This means either the symbols have to be defined/pulled into the global namespace to be discovered, or in the same namespace as any code using it. Not really ideal over just a named function that doesn't have any of these issues.

Answer (score 11):

Using C++20 you can get rid of begin() and end() with ranges.

```
#include <ranges>

std::ranges::copy(vec2, std::back_inserter(vec1));
```

or if you want to move elements:

```
std::ranges::move(vec2, std::back_inserter(vec1));
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use [vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

```
v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

Comment: Isn't this the same with the answer given by Tom Ritter and Robert Gamble in 2008?

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in strong exception guarantee (when copy constructor can throw an exception):

```
template<typename T>
inline void append_copy(std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2)
{
    const auto orig_v1_size = v1.size();
    v1.reserve(orig_v1_size + v2.size());
    try
    {
        v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        v1.erase(v1.begin() + orig_v1_size, v1.end());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Similar `append_move` with strong guarantee can't be implemented in general if vector element's move constructor can throw (which is unlikely but still).

Comment: Is it not possible for `v1.erase(...` to throw too?

Comment: `insert` already handles this. Also, this call to `erase` is equivalent to a `resize`.

Answer (score 9):

In C++23, it is possible to concatenate a range to a standard container using its member function `append_range`, if present.

Thus, the concatenation of two `std::vector` objects can be performed in following way:

```cpp
vec1.append_range(vec2);
```

Comment: +1 (though I wish I could give +100). This is by far the best possible answer when physical concatenation must take place. I have an answer of my own in this thread but it applies to cases where physical concatenation is not really needed in practice. It's a shame it took so long for C++ to incorporate sth like this. Finally in Rome :) Thx.

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is simply to iterate over the range of values for read-only purposes, an alternative is to wrap both vectors around a proxy (O(1)) instead of copying them (O(n)), so they are promptly seen as a single, contiguous one.

```
std::vector<int> A{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> B{ 10, 20, 30 };

VecProxy<int> AB(A, B);  // ----> O(1)!

for (size_t i = 0; i < AB.size(); i++)
    std::cout << AB[i] << " ";  // ----> 1 2 3 4 5 10 20 30
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55838758/2379625 for more details, including the 'VecProxy' implementation as well as pros & cons.

Answer (score 6):

Add this one to your header file:

```
template <typename T> vector<T> concat(vector<T> &a, vector<T> &b) {
    vector<T> ret = vector<T>();
    copy(a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(ret));
    copy(b.begin(), b.end(), back_inserter(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

and use it this way:

```
vector<int> a = vector<int>();
vector<int> b = vector<int>();

a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(2);
b.push_back(62);

vector<int> r = concat(a, b);
```

r will contain [1,2,62]

Comment: Don't know why this was down-voted. It may not be the most efficient way of doing this but it's not wrong and is effective.

Comment: And it works if you pass the same vector in as both parameters to concatenate a vector with itself.

Comment: @leeo non const ref args for one

Comment: @leeor_net ... and it's either `using namespace std;` or `using std::vector;` in the header file... or worse, it's putting this function template in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a general purpose solution using C++11 move semantics:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> concat(const std::vector<T>& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.empty()) return rhs;
    if (rhs.empty()) return lhs;
    std::vector<T> result {};
    result.reserve(lhs.size() + rhs.size());
    result.insert(result.cend(), lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend());
    result.insert(result.cend(), rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> concat(std::vector<T>&& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs.insert(lhs.cend(), rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    return std::move(lhs);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> concat(const std::vector<T>& lhs, std::vector<T>&& rhs)
{
    rhs.insert(rhs.cbegin(), lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend());
    return std::move(rhs);
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> concat(std::vector<T>&& lhs, std::vector<T>&& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.empty()) return std::move(rhs);
    lhs.insert(lhs.cend(), std::make_move_iterator(rhs.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(rhs.end()));
    return std::move(lhs);
}
```

Note how this differs from [`append`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210097/2970186)ing to a `vector`.

Comment: Have 1st call 2nd overload

Answer (score 4):

You can prepare your own template for + operator:

```
template <typename T> 
inline T operator+(const T & a, const T & b)
{
    T res = a;
    res.insert(res.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
    return res;
}
```

Next thing - just use +:

```
vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4};
vector<int> b{5, 6, 7, 8};
for (auto x: a + b)
    cout << x << " ";
cout << endl;
```

This example gives output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Using`T operator+(const T & a, const T & b)` is dangerous, it is better to use `vector<T> operator+(const vector<T> & a, const vector<T> & b)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<int> v2 = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(v1));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: This answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented this function which concatenates any number of containers, moving from rvalue-references and copying otherwise

```
namespace internal {

// Implementation detail of Concatenate, appends to a pre-reserved vector, copying or moving if
// appropriate
template<typename Target, typename Head, typename... Tail>
void AppendNoReserve(Target* target, Head&& head, Tail&&... tail) {
    // Currently, require each homogenous inputs. If there is demand, we could probably implement a
    // version that outputs a vector whose value_type is the common_type of all the containers
    // passed to it, and call it ConvertingConcatenate.
    static_assert(
            std::is_same_v<
                    typename std::decay_t<Target>::value_type,
                    typename std::decay_t<Head>::value_type>,
            "Concatenate requires each container passed to it to have the same value_type");
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Head>) {
        std::copy(head.begin(), head.end(), std::back_inserter(*target));
    } else {
        std::move(head.begin(), head.end(), std::back_inserter(*target));
    }
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Tail) > 0) {
        AppendNoReserve(target, std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    }
}

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
size_t TotalSize(const Head& head, const Tail&... tail) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Tail) > 0) {
        return head.size() + TotalSize(tail...);
    } else {
        return head.size();
    }
}

}  // namespace internal

/// Concatenate the provided containers into a single vector. Moves from rvalue references, copies
/// otherwise.
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
auto Concatenate(Head&& head, Tail&&... tail) {
    size_t totalSize = internal::TotalSize(head, tail...);
    std::vector<typename std::decay_t<Head>::value_type> result;
    result.reserve(totalSize);
    internal::AppendNoReserve(&result, std::forward<Head>(head), std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For containers which offer `push_back` (string, vector, deque, ...):

`std::copy(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::back_inserter(output))`

and

for containers which offer `insert` (maps, sets):

`std::copy(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::inserter(output, output.end()))`

Comment: For containers with `push_back` it's more efficient to call `v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end())` than to invoke pushing in a loop (which `std::copy` does)

Answer (score 1):

This solution might be a bit complicated, but `boost-range` has also some other nice things to offer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 4,5,6 };
    boost::copy(b, std::back_inserter(a));
    for (auto& iter : a) {
        std::cout << iter << " ";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Often ones intention is to combine vector `a` and `b` just iterate over it doing some operation. In this case, there is the ridiculous simple `join` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 4,5,6 };
    std::vector<int> c = { 7,8,9 };
    // Just creates an iterator
    for (auto& iter : boost::join(a, boost::join(b, c))) {
        std::cout << iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    // Can also be used to create a copy
    std::vector<int> d;
    boost::copy(boost::join(a, boost::join(b, c)), std::back_inserter(d));
    for (auto& iter : d) {
        std::cout << iter << " ";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

For large vectors this might be an advantage, as there is no copying. It can be also used for copying an generalizes easily to more than one container.

For some reason there is nothing like `boost::join(a,b,c)`, which could be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a way to append a vector to another after creation, [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) is your best bet, as has been answered several times, for example:

```
vector<int> first = {13};
const vector<int> second = {42};

first.insert(first.end(), second.cbegin(), second.cend());
```

Sadly there's no way to construct a `const vector<int>`, as above you must construct and then `insert`.

---

If what you're actually looking for is a container to hold the concatenation of these two `vector<int>`s, there may be something better available to you, if:

1. Your `vector` contains primitives
2. Your contained primitives are of size 32-bit or smaller
3. You want a `const` container

If the above are all true, I'd suggest using the [`basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) who's `char_type` matches the size of the primitive contained in your `vector`. You should include a [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) in your code to validate these sizes stay consistent:

```
static_assert(sizeof(char32_t) == sizeof(int));
```

With this holding true you can just do:

```
const u32string concatenation = u32string(first.cbegin(), first.cend()) + u32string(second.cbegin(), second.cend());
```

For more information on the differences between `string` and `vector` you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35558008/2642059

For a live example of this code you can look here: http://ideone.com/7Iww3I

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pre-implemented STL algorithms using a template for a polymorphic type use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>

void concat(std::vector<T>& valuesa, std::vector<T>& valuesb){

     for_each(valuesb.begin(), valuesb.end(), [&](int value){ valuesa.push_back(value);});
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values_p={1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> values_s={6,7};

   concat(values_p, values_s);

    for(auto& it : values_p){

        std::cout<<it<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can clear the second vector if you don't want to use it further (`clear()` method).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this task in C++17 without using the [rangesV3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/) library. After reading some posts in this topic, I made this solution:

```cpp
namespace algorithms
{
/*!
 * \brief Wraps incoming element and move/or copy the elements from one to another.
 * \example return (wrapped_plus(container) + ...).value
 */
template <class T>
struct wrapped_plus {
    using value_type = T;

    value_type value;

    wrapped_plus(value_type&& in) : value(std::move(in)) {}
    wrapped_plus(const value_type& in) : value(in) {}

    wrapped_plus operator+(const wrapped_plus& in)
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(in.value), std::end(in.value), std::back_inserter(value));
        return *this;
    }

    wrapped_plus operator+(wrapped_plus&& in)
    {
        std::move(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(in.value)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(in.value)), std::back_inserter(value));
        return *this;
    }
};

/*!
 * \brief Merge 2 or more STL containers with same type.
 * \example merge(container,container,container)
 */
template <typename... Containers>
static inline auto merge(Containers&&... c)
{
    return (wrapped_plus(c) + ...).value;
}
}  // namespace algorithms

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int> dest{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> src{6,7,8,9,10};

    auto result =  algorithms::merge(dest,src);

    return 0;
}
```

[COMPLETE EXAMPLE](https://onlinegdb.com/QaiHO9_Fd)

Answer (score -2):

Concatenate two `std::vector-s` with `for` loop in one `std::vector`.

```cpp
    std::vector <int> v1 {1, 2, 3}; //declare vector1
    std::vector <int> v2 {4, 5}; //declare vector2
    std::vector <int> suma; //declare vector suma

    for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) //for loop 1
    {
         suma.push_back(v1[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< v2.size(); i++) //for loop 2
    {
         suma.push_back(v2[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < suma.size(); i++) //for loop 3-output
    {
         std::cout << suma[i];
    }
```

Comment: besides it not working, this code is heavily non-idiomatic. You should at least be using `auto` iterators instead of manual indexing. You don't care about what index you are concatenating only that it is done sequentially.

Comment: @TarickWelling I don't see why you said this code is not working, could you be more specific ?

Comment: Did you check the date of my comment? You fixed the bugs in your code now it is just not idiomatic.

Answer (score -5):

To be honest, you could fast concatenate two vectors by copy elements from two vectors into the other one or just only append one of two vectors!. It depends on your aim.

**Method 1:** Assign new vector with its size is the sum of two original vectors' size.

```
vector<int> concat_vector = vector<int>();
concat_vector.setcapacity(vector_A.size() + vector_B.size());
// Loop for copy elements in two vectors into concat_vector
```

**Method 2:** Append vector A by adding/inserting elements of vector B.

```
// Loop for insert elements of vector_B into vector_A with insert() 
function: vector_A.insert(vector_A .end(), vector_B.cbegin(), vector_B.cend());
```

Comment: What does your answer add that hasn't already been provided in other answers?

Comment: @Mat: Bold characters.

Comment: If the original vector(s) are no longer needed after, it may be better to use `std::move_iterator` so that elements are moved instead of copied. (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator).

Comment: What is `setcapacity`? What is `function: `?

Comment: @L.F. I think he's talking about the `resize` method.

Answer (score -6):

Try, create two vectors and add second vector to first vector,
code:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3};
std::vector<int> v2{4,5};

for(int i = 0; i<v2.size();i++)
{
     v1.push_back(v2[i]);
}
```

v1:1,2,3.

Description:

While i int not v2 size, push back element , index i in v1 vector.

Comment: Your description is not clear (and  useless, sorry). Otherwise, your answer could be more complete if you add a second solution which save the concatenation in another vector rather than modifiying one of them.