# Copy private vectors between classes

Tags: c++, vector, private

Vectors if are data of a class should be assigned as private member of that class.
The class should provide the methods to access the vector methods needed.

Now I have my class Snake which encapsulate a snake for the classic game.

```
typedef std::vector<Polygon4>::const_iterator const_iterator;
enum directions{UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT, IN, OUT, FW, RW };

class Snake
{
private:
    enum directions head_dir;
    int cubes_taken;
    float score;
    struct_color snake_color;
    V4 head_pos;
    std::vector<Polygon4> p_list; //the vector
public:   

    Snake();
    V4 get_head_pos();
    Polygon4 create_cube(V4 point);
    void initialize_snake();
    void move(directions);

    void set_head_dir(directions dir);
    directions get_head_dir();
    void sum_cubes_taken(int x);
    int get_cube_taken();

    void sum_score(float x);
    float get_score();

    void set_snake_color();

 //vector manipulation functions
 const_iterator p_list_begin() const {return p_list.begin();}
 const_iterator p_list_end() const {return p_list.end();}
 void add_IntToP_list(Polygon4 cube){p_list.push_back(cube);}
 void clear_list(){p_list.clear();}
 unsigned int get_list_size(){return p_list.size();}

};
```

I have an other class in my program, the graphic management:

```
class MyGLBox{
private:
std::vector<Polygon4> p_list;
public:
     //do stuff...
     //management vectors:
     const_iterator p_list_begin() const {return p_list.begin();}
     const_iterator p_list_end() const {return p_list.end();}
     void add_IntToP_list(Polygon4 cube){p_list.push_back(cube););
     void clear_list(){p_list.clear();}
     unsigned int get_list_size(){return p_list.size();}
}
```

Now every frame in the game I need to copy the snake p_list into the MyGLbox p_list. If the vectors were public it would have been pretty easy:

```
myGLBox.p_list = snake.p_list;
```

now if they are private:

```
transfer_function(*MyGLBox box, *Snake snake){
    const_iterator cube;
    for(cube = snake->p_list_begin(); cube != snake->p_list_end(); cube++){
         box->add_InTop_list(*cube);
    }
}
```

is it right what I'm trying to do? Is there a better way to do it? To me the for cycle seems pretty inefficent

Comment: you should use `++cube` instead of `cube++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a function

```
void add_IntToP_list(Polygon4 cube){p_list.push_back(cube););
```

for adding a single element, you can add another overload for adding a range of elements

```
void add_IntToP_list(vector<Polygon4>::const_iterator first, 
                      vector<Polygon4>::const_iterator last)
{ p_list.insert(p_list.end(), first, last); }
```

and then call that with the range you want to add, maybe

```
box->add_IntToP_list(snake->p_list_begin(), snake->p_list_end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a friend function:

```
void transfer_function(MyGLBox * box, Snake * snake )
{
    box->p_list = snake->p_list;
}

// in class MyGlBox
friend void transfer_function(MyGLBox *, Snake *);

// in class Snake
friend void transfer_function(MyGLBox *, Snake *);
```

But if you have multiple such scenarios, this can easily become unmanageable.

Alternatively, you could still expose the vector directly via a get member. E.g:

```
// in class MyGLBox
std::vector<Polygon4> & get_p_list( )
{
    return p_list;
}
```

It's not necessarily always "bad" if you return the vector itself - since you expose a lot of the vector's functionality anyways, it's not like the user has been given unwanted control over the data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear that friendship violates the programming exercise.  I think your method is correct in that it provides the accessors to the private vector, and I agree, it is inefficient copying all that data.  One optimisation you can do is to extend the vector:

```
v.reserve(v.size() + distance(v_prime.begin(),v_prime.end()));
v.insert(v.end(),v_prime.begin(),v_prime.end());
```

I robbed the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313432/c-extend-a-vector-with-another-vector).

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do it. One way is to `friend` your other functions so it can access your `vector` like a public variable.

Another is to make the variable itself `public`. Some may argue it's not good practice etc, but that's ridiculous. Are you trying to "protect" the `vector` from yourself?! Is that how confident you are in your own programming? To me, making `private` is only good for when you are writing a library for others to use not in your own program.

And finally, a remark on what you said. The `for` loop you presented is not at all inefficient. It **is** less efficient than using `=`, true, but adding one by one is also not that bad. `vector`'s amortized performance is `O(1)`. In fact if inserting something was intended to have cost `1`, adding in vector has amortized cost `2`.

Comment: I want to make the project open source and I want that the other programmers (if there will be) will be able to use/understand what I did. but thx anyway for the answer :D

Comment: I would still suggest good documentation instead of making it private. If you insist however, I suggest using `friend`. You don't need to friend the whole other class, you could use the `friend class::function;` so to friend only that particular function.