# Insert or push_back to end of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, stl, insert

Is there any difference in performance between the two methods below to insert new elements to the end of a `std::vector`:

### Method 1

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1 };
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(3);
vec.push_back(4);
vec.push_back(5);
```

### Method 2

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1 };
int arr[] = { 2,3,4,5 };
vec.insert(std::end(vec), std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Personally, I like **method 2** because it is nice and concise and inserts all the new elements from an array in one go. But

- is there any difference in performance?
- After all, they do the same thing. Don't they?

### Update

The reason why I am not initializing the vector with all the elements, to begin with, is that in my program I am adding the remaining elements based on a condition.

Comment: There is also another option: `std::vector<int> vec { 1,2,3,4,5  };`

Comment: Create a small test program where you do each a million times. Build with optimizations enabled, and test and measure.

Comment: Oh and while the end result (a vector with five elements) the two methods do different things. The most important difference is the allocation and reallocation of the data needed for the elements in the vector. The first variant could lead to four reallocations, and with a possibly different capacity and size, while the second variant there's probably only a single reallocation and maybe the same capacity and size.

Comment: *Personally I like method 2 because it's nice and concise and inserts all the new elements from an array in one go.* That's the important reason, performance is secondary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> After all, they do the same thing. Don't they?

No. They are different. The first method using [`std::vector::push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will undergo several reallocations compared to [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

The `insert` will internally allocate memory, according to the current [`std::vector::capacity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) before copying the range. See the following discussion for more:

[Does std::vector::insert reserve by definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359169/does-stdvectorinsert-reserve-by-definition/35359472)

---

> But is there any difference in performance?

Due to the reason explained above, the second method would show slight performance improvement. For instance, see the quick benck-mark below, using *http://quick-bench.com*:

**[See online bench-mark](http://quick-bench.com/nB9y2OESlyTJsozER61ueCDOZ2g)**

### [image]

Or write a test program to measure the performance(as *@Some programmer dude* mentioned in the comments). Following is a sample test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std::chrono;

class Timer final
{
private:
    time_point<high_resolution_clock> _startTime;

public:
    Timer() noexcept
        : _startTime{ high_resolution_clock::now() }
    {}
    ~Timer() noexcept {  Stop(); }
    void Stop() noexcept
    {
        const auto endTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
        const auto start = time_point_cast<microseconds>(_startTime).time_since_epoch();
        const auto end = time_point_cast<microseconds>(endTime).time_since_epoch();
        const auto durationTaken = end - start;
        const auto duration_ms = durationTaken * 0.001;
        std::cout << durationTaken.count() << "us (" << duration_ms.count() << "ms)\n";
    }
};
// Method 1: push_back
void push_back()
{
    std::cout << "push_backing:    ";
    Timer time{};
    for (auto i{ 0ULL }; i < 1000'000; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> vec = { 1 };
        vec.push_back(2);
        vec.push_back(3);
        vec.push_back(4);
        vec.push_back(5);
    }
}
// Method 2: insert_range
void insert_range()
{
    std::cout << "range-inserting: ";
    Timer time{};
    for (auto i{ 0ULL }; i < 1000'000; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> vec = { 1 };
        int arr[] = { 2,3,4,5 };
        vec.insert(std::end(vec), std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr));
    }
}

int main()
{
    push_back();
    insert_range();
    return 0;
}
```

release building with my system(MSVS2019:*/Ox /std:c++17*, *AMD Ryzen 7 2700x*<sub>(8-core, 3.70 Ghz)</sub>, *x64 Windows 10*)

```
// Build - 1
push_backing:    285199us (285.199ms)
range-inserting: 103388us (103.388ms)

// Build - 2
push_backing:    280378us (280.378ms)
range-inserting: 104032us (104.032ms)

// Build - 3
push_backing:    281818us (281.818ms)
range-inserting: 102803us (102.803ms)
```

Which shows for the given scenario, `std::vector::insert` ing is about `2.7` times faster than `std::vector::push_back`.

See what other compilers(*clang 8.0 and gcc 9.2*) wants to say, according to their implementations: https://godbolt.org/z/DQrq51

Comment: Wow! The graphs show that insert is much better in performance in this case.

Comment: @jacobi Yeap. Also note that the [`std::vector:::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) will bring the performance at the same level. **[See here](http://quick-bench.com/nEAR80hw3Os5kwR0oQGlOpMEL9A)** Therefore reserve the memory, if you know the size beforehand, and avoid unwanted reallocations.

Comment: @JeJo: Note also that, from your link: "When inserting a range, the range version of `insert()` is generally preferable as it preserves the correct capacity growth behavior, unlike `reserve()` followed by a series of `push_back()`s." In other words, `reserve()` will either cause a realloc or do nothing, and if it causes a realloc, you will probably end up with a full or nearly full vector after doing the `push_back()` calls. That is wasteful since it means you'll be doing another realloc in the near future.

Comment: @mirabilos the purpose of the website is to give a comparison between the code snippets, rather providing an accurate x-y axis measures. Incase of accurate benchmarking, one should write a test program and has to measure for certain times. For instance, further interests, following is a test-program that I tried: https://godbolt.org/z/DQrq51

Comment: @JeJo ah, thanks. I didn’t follow the link because what’s supplied on SO “ought to be enough” and most of the external things don’t work on my browser anyway. The changed image will do, thanks! (So, smaller bar = better.)

Answer (score 12):

There may be a difference between the two approaches if the vector needs to reallocate.

Your second method, calling the `insert()` member function once with an iterator range:

```
vec.insert(std::end(vec), std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

would be able to provide the optimisation of allocating all the memory needed for the insertion of the elements in one blow since `insert()` is getting *random access iterators*, i.e., it takes constant time to know the size of the range, so the whole memory allocation can be done before copying the elements, and no reallocations during the call would follow.

Your first method, individual calls to the `push_back()` member function, may trigger several reallocations, depending on the number of elements to insert and the memory initially reserved for the vector.

Note that the optimisation explained above may not be available for *forward* or *bidirectional iterators* since it would take linear time in the size of the range to know the number of elements to be inserted. However, the time needed for multiple memory allocations likely dwarfs the time needed to calculate the length of the range for these cases, so probably they still implement this optimisation. For *input iterators*, this optimisation is not even possible since they are single-pass iterators.

Answer (score 6):

The major contributing factor is going to be the re-allocations. `vector` has to make space for new elements.

Consider these 3 sinppets.

```
 //pushback
 std::vector<int> vec = {1};
 vec.push_back(2);
 vec.push_back(3);
 vec.push_back(4);
 vec.push_back(5);

 //insert
 std::vector<int> vec = {1};
 int arr[] = {2,3,4,5};
 vec.insert(std::end(vec), std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));


 //cosntruct
 std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

[image]

To confirm the reallocations coming into picture, after adding a `vec.reserve(5)` in pushback and insert versions, we get the below results.

[image]

Comment: Interesting how adding reserve brings down the time for push_back and insert to similar levels.

Comment: Why would one want to add `reserve()` to the `insert()` version? I don't get the same performance hit as you when doing it though: http://quick-bench.com/4ioxDEyzxMl37C7eHfNICKk0Tpc

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did with clang. Don't know why `clang`'s insert is slower.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that was a surprise! ... and using `clang++` + `libc++(LLVM)` made it even worse: http://quick-bench.com/jfcVMGkhgFRI33-2PMPR74cM1G0

Answer (score 4):

`push_back` inserts a single element, hence in the worst case you may encounter multiple reallocations.

For the sake of the example, consider the case where the initial capacity is 2 and increases by a factor of 2 on each reallocation. Then

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1 }; 
vec.push_back(2);             
vec.push_back(3);                 // need to reallocate, capacity is 4
vec.push_back(4);                   
vec.push_back(5);                  // need to reallocate, capacity is 8
```

You can of course prevent unnecessary reallocations by calling

```
vec.reserve(num_elements_to_push);
```

Though, if you anyhow insert from an array, the more idomatic way is to use `insert`.