# transform a vector<vector<Point> > x in a vector<Point> y

Tags: c++, vector

I have a  `vector < vector < Point> > X` and want to copy all the elements in it into a `vector < Point > Y` (and in the same order if is possible)
I tried something like (in a for cycle):

```
Y.push_back(i) = X.at(i).at(i);
```

but obviously it doesn't work...

I also find this (on stackoverflow) but it doesn't work for me as well...

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<Point> >::iterator it = X.begin(), itEnd = X.end(); it != itEnd; ++it)
    Y.push_back((*it));
```

but the compiler tells me that "there isn't an instance of function in overload" (and honestly I don't even know what does it mean).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it = X.begin(); it != X.end(); ++it)
     Y.insert(Y.end(), it->begin(), it->end());
```

If you know the size of the resulting vector, you could call `Y.reserve(finalYSize)` before the loop.

Comment: For people not using c++11 add a space between `>>`. i.e: `for(vector< vector<Point> >::iterator it = X.begin(); it != X.end(); ++it)`

Comment: Thanks, forgot about it... C++11 ftw!

Comment: a question, as well we are here :P why it would be important (i think) to do the .reserve and give a size to the vector?wich is the difference if i don't do it? (and in the specific case, i wouldn't do it, because i don't know exactly the size of the resulting vector). thx again.

Comment: In C++11, you should obviously use the much more readable range-based for-loop `for (auto& subvct: X) Y.insert(Y.end(), subvct.begin(), subvct.end());`, which is completely equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Y.push_back(i) = X.at(i).at(i);
```

This takes element `i` from the vector `i`. If you want to copy all the elements:

```
 vector<vector<Point> > X;
 vector<Point> Y;
 //....
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < X.size() ; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < X[i].size() ; j++ )
       Y.push_back(X[i][j]);
```

Edit: As per the comments and the other answer, the more C++-ish way of doing it is found also in this question - [What is the best way to concatenate two vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177241/best-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors)

Comment: I would suggest using `insert` instead of the inner for loop.

Comment: This is correct. Just some additional readings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177241/best-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/how-to-concat-two-stl-vectors

Comment: really really really thanks! :) also this method works perfectly :)