# Inserting a vector transformation

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I earlier posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545184/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors-whilst-transforming-elements) on the optimal way to *concatenate* two `std::vector`s, where one vector must first be transformed. While the obvious solution using `std::transform` may not be the theoretically optimal solution, the cost of the multiple capacity checks are unlikely to be significant.

But if we consider the more general problem of *inserting* one vector which must be transformed into another, then there is now a potential significant overhead involved.

What is the optimal method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few options here:

**Method 1: temp transform**

```
std::vector<T1> temp {};
temp.reserve(vec.size());
std::transform(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(temp), op);
vec1.insert(vec1.begin() + pos, std::make_move_iterator(temp.begin()),
               std::make_move_iterator(temp.end()));
```

But now the overhead is not a trivial capacity check, instead the additional costs is an allocation/deallocation of `size_of(T1) * vec2.size()` for `temp`. This could easily be a significant cost if `vec2` is large.

**Method 2: loop insert**

```
vec1.reserve(vec1.size() + vec2.size());
std::size_t i {pos};
for (const auto& p : vec2) {
    vec1.insert(vec1.begin() + i, op);
    ++i;
}
```

This avoids the additional allocation/deallocation of method 1 but there is another serious problem with this solution: each of the `n = vec1.size() - pos` elements in `vec1` have to be shifted `n` times, a `O(n^2)` operation.

**Method 3: shift and copy**

```
vec1.resize(vec1.size() + pair_vec.size());
std::move(vec1.begin() + pos, vec1.end(), vec1.begin() + pos + vec2.size());
std::transform(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec1.begin() + pos, op);
```

This seems to be close to what we want, we only pay for an 'extra' `n` default constructors.

**EDIT**

My *shift and copy method (3)* was incorrect, it should be:

```
auto v1_size = vec1.size();
vec1.resize(vec1.size() + vec2.size());
std::move(vec1.begin() + pos, vec1.begin() + v1_size, vec1.begin() + pos + vec2.size());
std::transform(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec1.begin() + pos, op);
```

**TESTS ( updated with @VaughnCato's and @ViktorSehr's methods)**

I tested methods 1 & 3 (method 2 is clearly not going to perform well - easy to verify), along with the methods suggested by [@VaughnCato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552578/2970186) and [@ViktorSehr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28551784/2970186). Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

using std::size_t;

std::vector<int> generate_random_ints(size_t n)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    auto seed1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    generator.seed((unsigned) seed1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform {};
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    std::generate_n(v.begin(), n, [&] () { return uniform(generator); });
    return v;
}

std::vector<std::string> generate_random_strings(size_t n)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    auto seed1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    generator.seed((unsigned) seed1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform {};
    std::vector<std::string> v(n);
    std::generate_n(v.begin(), n, [&] () { return std::to_string(uniform(generator)); });
    return v;
}

template <typename D=std::chrono::nanoseconds, typename F>
D benchmark(F f, unsigned num_tests)
{
    D total {0};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_tests; ++i) {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        f();
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        total += std::chrono::duration_cast<D>(end - start);
    }
    return D {total / num_tests};
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename UnaryOperation>
void temp_transform(std::vector<T1> vec1, const std::vector<T2> &vec2, size_t pos, UnaryOperation op)
{
    std::vector<T1> temp {};
    temp.reserve(vec2.size());
    std::transform(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(temp), op);
    vec1.insert(vec1.begin() + pos, std::make_move_iterator(temp.begin()),
                std::make_move_iterator(temp.end()));
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename UnaryOperation>
void shift_copy(std::vector<T1> vec1, const std::vector<T2> &vec2, size_t pos, UnaryOperation op)
{
    auto v1_size = vec1.size();
    vec1.resize(vec1.size() + vec2.size());
    std::move(vec1.begin() + pos, vec1.begin() + v1_size, vec1.begin() + pos + vec2.size());
    std::transform(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec1.begin() + pos, op);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename UnaryOperation>
void boost_transform(std::vector<T1> vec1, const std::vector<T2> &vec2, size_t pos, UnaryOperation op)
{
    auto v2_begin = boost::make_transform_iterator(vec2.begin(), op);
    auto v2_end   = boost::make_transform_iterator(vec2.end(), op);
    vec1.insert(vec1.begin() + pos, v2_begin, v2_end);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename UnaryOperation>
void boost_adapter(std::vector<T1> vec1, const std::vector<T2> &vec2, size_t pos, UnaryOperation op)
{
   auto transformed_range = vec2 | boost::adaptors::transformed(op);
   vec1.insert(vec1.begin() + pos, transformed_range.begin(), transformed_range.end());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned num_tests {1000};
    size_t vec1_size {1000000};
    size_t vec2_size {1000000};
    size_t insert_pos {vec1_size / 2};

    // Switch the variable names to inverse test
    auto vec2 = generate_random_ints(vec1_size);
    auto vec1 = generate_random_strings(vec2_size);

    //auto op = [] (const std::string& str) { return std::stoi(str); };
    auto op = [] (int i) { return std::to_string(i); };

    auto f_temp_transform_insert = [&vec1, &vec2, &insert_pos, &op] () {
        temp_transform(vec1, vec2, insert_pos, op);
    };
    auto f_shift_copy_insert = [&vec1, &vec2, &insert_pos, &op] () {
        shift_copy(vec1, vec2, insert_pos, op);
    };
    auto f_boost_transform_insert = [&vec1, &vec2, &insert_pos, &op] () {
        boost_transform(vec1, vec2, insert_pos, op);
    };
   auto f_boost_adapter_insert = [&vec1, &vec2, &insert_pos, &op] () {
       boost_adapter(vec1, vec2, insert_pos, op);
   };

    auto temp_transform_insert_time  = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(f_temp_transform_insert, num_tests).count();
    auto shift_copy_insert_time      = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(f_shift_copy_insert, num_tests).count();
    auto boost_transform_insert_time = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(f_boost_transform_insert, num_tests).count();
    auto boost_adapter_insert_time   = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(f_boost_adapter_insert, num_tests).count();

    std::cout << "temp_transform: " << temp_transform_insert_time << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "shift_copy: " << shift_copy_insert_time << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "boost_transform: " << boost_transform_insert_time << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "boost_adapter: " << boost_adapter_insert_time << "ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**RESULTS**

Compiled with:

```
g++ vector_insert.cpp -std=c++11 -O3 -o vector_insert_test
```

The mean user-runtimes are:

```
|    Method   | std::string -> int (ms) | int -> std::string (ms) |
|:-----------:|:-----------------------:|:-----------------------:|
| 1           |            68           |           220           |
| 3           |            67           |           222           |
| @VaughnCato |            71           |           239           |
| @ViktorSehr |            72           |           236           |
```

**TLDR**

- The `boost` methods are not as fast as the `std::transform` methods.
- The `std::transform` methods are almost equally good - although there is a difficult to interpret discrepancy between `int` -> `std::string` and `std::string` -> `int` performance.

Answer (score 1):

@VaughnCato's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552578/3422652) of using `boost::transform_iterator` for your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545184/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors-whilst-transforming-elements) should work well for this one also:

```
auto vec1begin = boost::make_transform_iterator(vec1.begin(), f);
auto vec1end = boost::make_transform_iterator(vec1.end(), f);
vec2.insert(middle, vec1begin, vec1end);
```

Comment: yes I noticed.. I was just about to give him the good news :p

Comment: I can't replicate VaughnCato's results (see my answer in first question, and edit to my answer in this question).

Answer (score 0):

How about using *[boost::range::adaptors::transformed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html)* ?

```
std::vector<...> first_vector;
auto transform_functor = [](...){...};
auto transformed_range = first_vector | boost::adaptors::transformed(transform_functor):
some_vector.insert(some_vector.end(), transformed_range.begin(), transformed_range.end());
```

Given that *boost::transform* and the *vector::insert* function is implemented as clever as possible, this ought to be able to ignore any unnessesary capacity checks.

Comment: I can't seem to get this method to work (see the edit in my answer), if you can point out where I'm going wrong I'll update the results to include your method.

Comment: your method is working now... it doesn't perform as well as the STL methods.

Comment: Well in a perfect world it should be the optimal way, but I guess unnessesary cycles are added somewhere in the transform operation with a transform range.