# inserting into vectors c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I need to push 66,000 vectors (the number of vectors is not fixed, it can be 90,000 vectors also. For the sake of brevity I am showing the below code with the example of 66,000 vectors) of type vector into the following vector:

```
vector<int> vec;
```

The size of each of the 66,000 vectors is 9,000 elements. I am using the following for doing the same:

```
vec.reserve(66000*9000);
for(int j=0;j<66000;j++)
    for(int i=0;i<9000;i++) //9000 elements in vec1[i] per vector is not fixed
        vec.push_back(vec1[i]); //i am pushing i as an example
```

Is there someway by which I may increase the efficiency of this code?

I need to concatenate too many vectors, so a solution for the same is potentially different from concatenating two vectors. Also I can not use multi-threading as mentioned in the previous question

Comment: if the size is fixed, why not use an array / `std::array` instead?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff Because it is big. Of course one could dynamically allocate an `std::array`, but what would that help?

Comment: Is the double usage of 'i' intentional?

Comment: @FooBar It works, but I agree, this is quite unreadable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to concatenate two vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177241/best-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors)

Comment: @FooBar The double usage of i was unintensional

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff I am afraid the size is not fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve( 66000*other_vec.size() );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 66000; i++ ) 
{
    vec.insert( vec.end(), other_vec.begin(), other_vec.end() );
}
```

Comment: is insert faster then push_back? If yes, what is the reason for the same

Comment: @Steg Verner I think that insert is faster because at least general calculations are made only once.

Comment: @StegVerner interval insertion is known to be faster. Check Scott Meyers "Effective STL" book. Good reading, though

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`resize()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) instead of [`reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/). Remove `push_back` when `resize()` is used. Memory is allocated with `resize()` and initializes. `reserve` just allocates but doesn't initialize.

Comment: He must remove `push_back` then. Also i think this will give too small benefit.

Comment: @PSIAlt _"Also i think this will give too small benefit."_ Not with many small reallocations.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What reallocation? He already reserves enough memory.

Comment: I do not see how this is supposed to help.

Comment: I have to down vote as using `resize()` will break using `push_back()`

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the underlying data directly via data():

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Then you can copy the data directly (e.g. just memcpy).

```
std::vector<int> foo;
for (int i=0; i<10;++i){
    foo.push_back(i);
}

std::vector<int> bar;

bar.resize(10*10);

int pos = 0;
int size = foo.size()*sizeof(int);
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i){
    memcpy(bar.data()+pos/sizeof(int),foo.data(),size);
    pos += size;
}


for (size_t i=0; i<bar.size(); ++i){
    cout << i << " " << bar[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: The STL uses memcpy internally anyway when it is safe to do so. See: http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/159916-memcpy-memmove-and-memset-are-deprecated. This is way too complicated/error prone and doesn't actually buy you anything.