# How to return large vector from class without copying data

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am writing a program in which a class has a data member that is a big `std::vector` (on the order of 100k - 1M items). Other classes need to be able to access this vector. At the moment I have a standard accessor function that returns the vector, but this returns a copy of the vector I believe. I think it would be more memory and time efficient to just return an iterator or a pointer to the first element. However, if I do this, how can one then use this pointer to run through the `vector` and know when to stop (i.e. where the vector ends)?

My code looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::vector<MyObj> objects_;
        //...

    public:
        std::vector<MyObj> getObjects() { return objects_; }
        //...
}
```

This question arises in another form for me when I want to run through (simulated) concatenated vectors. If I have a `vector` of `MyClass`, I'd like to be able to iterate over all of the contained `object_` vectors. I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3178194/3427580) that boost::join does what I have in mind, but I think I need to return copies for it to work. Can I return a pointer to the vector and still retain the ability to iterate over it and others in succession?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid the performance penalties, return references.

```
// Non-const version
std::vector<MyObj>& getObjects() { return objects_;}

// const version
std::vector<MyObj> const& getObjects() const { return objects_; }
```

However, before you make that change, you have to consider the downsides of exposing references to a member variable. It makes your class less flexible. You can't easily change `objects_` to a different type of container if that made more sense without impacting all the users of the class.

Comment: Could you please explain further why exposing references makes it harder to change the container type? Do you mean the templated type?

Comment: @marcman, if your container needed to be a set instead of a list, you can't easily change `objects_` to be of type `std::set<MyObj>`. That would break all the clients that were depending on `objects_` to be of type `std::vector<MyObj>`.

Comment: @marcman See a solution for the change of container in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Make your class act as a collection by delegating to the `vector` data member.
Of course, you may need to revisit the code that consumes `MyClass`
but, with the `getObjects()` commented out, the compiler will tell you where + most of the changes are *likely* to be on the line of

```
MyClass heapsOfThem;
// ...
// just delete the `getObjects()` *and use MyClass::iterator*
// instead of std::vector::iterator.
// for(std::vector<MyObj>::iterator it=
//    heapsOfThem.getObjects().begin()...
// )
for(MyClass::iterator it=heapsOfThem.begin()...)
```

Delegation code goes on the line of the below - once you fixed your calling code, you can change your mind what type (vector, list, set) to use as an internal container for your objects without changes in the calling code.

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::vector<MyObj> objects_;
        //...

    public:


        const size_t size() const {
          return objects_,size();
        }
        MyObj& operator[](size_t i) {
          return objects_[i];
        }
        const MyObj& operator[](size_t i) const {
          return objects_[i];
        }

        using iterator = std::vector<MyObj>::iterator;
        iterator begin() {
          return objects_.begin();
        }
        iterator end() {
          return objects_.end();
        }
        // TODO const iterators following the same pattern

        // *if you aren't good enough with the above*
        // uncomment it and let it return a *reference* 
        // std::vector<MyObj>& getObjects() { return objects_; }
        //...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really avoid the problems of changing the set type - the calling code has the same dependency on `std::vector<MyObj>::iterator`.

Comment: @M.M "This doesn't really avoid the problems " yes, it does. Thanks for showing there is a need for an extra explanation, I added it

Comment: The calling code could still avoid any source changes when the container changes, even in the case of returning `vector`.

Comment: @M.M - "The calling code could still avoid any source changes when the container changes," - well, of course it could.

Comment: Yes, so what is the benefit of returning iterators instead of vector?

Comment: @M.M Really? How is you question different from asking "So, what is the benefit of encapsulation?"

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the class to have public methods that return an element of the array, and the size of the array, so all other classes can fetch values, without any copying of the entire vector.

```
public:
    unsigned int getMyObjArraySize();
    MyObj getMyObjElementAt(unsigned int index);
```

With this approach, there is only one instance of the vector, but any collaborations can be done via the two public methods that expose the size and an accessor to values via the index.

This approach is geared to the use of for-loops and not iterators.

```
MyClass myClass;
// ...
MyObj myObj;

for(unsigned int i; i < myClass.getMyObjArraySize(); i++) {
    myObj = myClass.getMyObjElementAt(i);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is ultimately I need to run through the entire vector, and I'd like to do it without copying all the data. Your `getMyObjectElementAt` returns a copy of each element, so ultimately it's no different than just returning the whole vector and iterating through it

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem returning a pointer to the vector.

```
std::vector<MyObj>* getObjects() { return &objects_; }
```

And then when want to iterate over it, just dereference:

```
std::vector<MyObj>* objectsPtr = getObjects();
for (auto& it : *objectsPtr)
{
   ...
}
```

However, make sure that you aren't writing to the vector while reading from it, since that would invalidate the iterator.