# keeping the same vector throughout the function for additions and deletions

Tags: c++, vector

I am creating a vector b1 with fixed size (like c-style array), for copying a1 followed a2.
I thought of using assign as below, But size of b1 is reduced to 7(to size of a1) after b1.assign(). How can I keep the b1 size 20 (fixed size) even after assign().
Any suggestions, I am using memcpy() now.

```
std::vector<int> a1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::vector<int> a2{ 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 };
std::vector<int> b1(20);
b1.assign(a1.begin(),a1.end());
```

Comment: Why not construct the vector from the iterators and then `resize` the vector to the final size you want?

Comment: What happens if the total length of `a1` and `a2` exceeds 20?  What do you do with the excess elements?

Comment: Note: if all want to do is concatenate two vectors, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177241/what-is-the-best-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy things, you can use [`std:copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
std::copy(a1.begin(), a1.end(), b1.begin());
```

Comment: I hope the second argument is a1.end(). And we need to repeat the same for copying a2.