# Concatenating two vector<cv::String> in OpenCV using C++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, concatenation

How to efficiently concatenate two vectors of cv::String type in OpenCV?
I have the following method that uses cv::glob method from openCv to return all filenames from a directory, an the method parameter is a vector of directories names.

```
vector<String> GetTrainingImageFiles(vector<string> directories)
{
vector<cv::String> allFiles;      //this will hold all the file names
vector<cv::String> directoryFiles;// this will hold a specific directory files for one iteration
for(string directory : directories)
{
    cv::String path(directory + "/*.ppm"); //select only ppm
    vector<cv::Mat> data;
    cv::glob(path, directoryFiles, false);
    //Here the directoryFiles vector should be concatenated to allFiles vector
}
return directoryFiles;
}
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Which vectors are you trying to concatenate?

Comment: @NathanOliver The directoryFiles to a second vector, I will edit the code to be more specific

Comment: This isn't really an OpenCV question, as much as a general c++ std::vector question.  See: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177241/what-is-the-best-way-to-concatenate-two-vectors

Comment: @msmith81886 I think the referenced answer should do the job, thanks!