# merge vector into existing vector

Tags: c++, optimization, stl

In C++, given `vector<T> src, dst`, both already sorted, is there a *more efficient* way to merge the contents of `src` into `dst` than

```
size_t n = dst.size();
dst.insert(dst.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
std::inplace_merge(dst.begin(), dst.begin() + n, dst.end());
```

?  In the case I care about, `T` is a small (12-16 bytes, depending on ABI) POD structure, but each vector contains millions of elements, so the total amount of memory in play is tens to hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: I think the last parameter to `inplace_merge` needs to be `dst.end()` not `dst.size()`.

Comment: Mark: You are correct, and I had it right in my source file, but somehow mangled it when writing up the question.  Fixed now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating Two STL Vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stl-vectors)

Comment: @yes123: That question is not about merging sorted vectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would at least try:

```
std::vector<T> tmp;
tmp.reserve(src.size() + dst.size()); // commenters are probably right about this
std::merge(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin(), dst.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp));
src.swap(tmp);
```

But I suspect that much depends on the nature of `T`, the size of `src` and `dst`, and why we need to optimize.

Comment: To avoid growing `tmp` with a `back_inserter`, why not construct it as `std::vector<T> tmp(src.size() + dst.size())`?  Or use `reserve`?

Comment: @Oli, I'd rather use `reserve` in case default construction is expensive.

Comment: That would construct lots of elements -- why not just `reserve` the vector before the merging?

Comment: Sure, `.reserve()` is a good idea here... edited accordingly.

Comment: And if `T` is a nasty type, expensive to copy, then you could unpack `merge` and change it to default-construct and then swap from the orginal, rather than copying. C++0x has a `push_back(T &&)`, but that won't be used without help since the thing being pushed isn't necessarily disposable, so combine this answer with Cory's.

Comment: I might try this, but the vectors in question are potentially *very* large (each element is small, but there could be millions) so I expect that would wind up hurting more than it helps.

Comment: Months later: this was, in fact, an improvement over what I had, although not as much as I was hoping.  An improvement of the magnitude I wanted probably requires a smarter algorithm, and I'm no longer working on that particular problem, so this'll do for the accepted answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Why it give me error on `std::back_inserter(tmp));` as i am using it with string , `std::vector<string> tmp;` , 
`Error : std ahs member back_inserter`

Comment: It comes from `<iterator>`.

Answer (score 9):

It can be done more efficiently if T is heavy to copy and your compiler supports C++0x.

```
#include <iterator> // for make_move_iterator

size_t n = dst.size();

dst.insert(dst.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(src.end()));

std::inplace_merge(dst.begin(), dst.begin() + n, dst.end());
```

Using `make_move_iterator()` will cause `insert()` to move the contents of `src` into `dst` instead of copying them.

**Update:**

You're dealing with POD types and you're already resizing/copying everything in the `dst` vector in the likely case that `insert()` overflows the reserve, so it could be faster to just use `std::merge()` into a new `vector`.  This would avoid that initial copy AND have a better worst-case complexity:

`inplace_merge()` has a best case of O(*n*) complexity, but degrades into a worst-case O(*n* log *n*) depending on your data.

`merge()` has a worst-case O(*n*) so it is guaranteed to be at least as fast, potentially much faster.  It also has move optimization built-in.

Comment: It should be `dst.end()` in the final line, and you can probably make `n` const.

Comment: And if T is heavy to copy but your compiler doesn't support move semantics, you could resize dst and then swap each element of src into place. Obviously T needs an optimized swap. And I've never used `inplace_merge`, but it looks as though it does a lot of assignment and/or copying, which might kill performance anyway in the absence of move.

Comment: In the case I care about, T is a small (12 bytes, possibly padded to 16 in a `vector`) POD structure, so it seems to me that copy and move will both degenerate to `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes.  In that case you can still try the `merge` suggestion in the other answer.  He doesn't say it, but `merge` can actually be more efficient depending on your data:  `inplace_merge` is O(n) in the best case, and O(n log n) in the worst.  `merge` is always O(n).

Comment: The vectors potentially have millions of elements, I don't think copying everything to a new vector is a good idea.

Comment: @Zack: you're going to copy (nearly) everything anyway, unless you're really lucky and (nearly) all of `src` is greater than (nearly) all of `dst`. The difference is that `inplace_merge` (usually) copies everything more than once, and (if necessary) uses less RAM as working space.

Answer (score 0):

If default initialization of your elements is a lot cheaper than copying, you could eliminate the `insert` call and resize your destination vector. Then implement your own merge, going backwards - keep iterators to the end of the source and the old end of the destination, and move or copy to the new end of the destination. When you reach the beginning of the source, you're done.