# Under-the-hood STL: Concatenating an std::vector to itself without new vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have an STL vector that stores the diagonals of a matrix. A certain mathematical rule I'm implementing tells me that I can produce a new matrix of a tensor product's diagonals simply by taking the original vector and concatenating a copy of that vector onto itself (it doubles in size, and the values repeat after 1/2 * size() ).

I wrote the following code:

```
std::vector<int> aVec;

for (int k = 0; k < aVec.size(); k++) aVec.insert(aVec.end(), aVec[k]);
```

But I get seg-faults when I try this. If I create a copy of aVec and use that as the insert "value", as well as using it for the size() in the loop args, it will work, but I must do **both** of these things (otherwise I will still get seg-faults).

Can anyone explain what's going on underneath that makes this implementation not work?

Comment: There's a nice [insert method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201729/962089) of concatenating two vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will copy items indefinitely. Note how many to copy up front:

```
size_t n = aVec.size();
for (int k = 0; k != n; ++k)
  aVec.push_back(aVec[k]);
```

While many C++ algorithms are better expressed using `begin()` and `end()` iterators, in this case your access via index is superior, because modifying the container might invalidate the iterators, but the element access will remain valid. You can, however, use `reserve` to avoid that invalidation:

```
aVec.reserve(2*aVec.size());
std::copy(aVec.begin(), aVec.end(), std::back_inserter(aVec));
```

Comment: This may work in some implementations, but it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Which of the two? The first I'd consider well within the specs. The latter is not perfectly within the specs: “Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence. No reallocation shall take place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`.” But `end()` is not an iterator referring to an element, so it might *in theory* get invalidated. I can think of no way to implement vector so that it gets invalidated.

Comment: Reallocation isn't the only operation that causes invalidation.  Any insertion or deletion invalidates handles (iterators/pointers/references) at or after the insertion/deletion point.  Handles before the insertion/deletion point are ok, but `end()` is not before the insertion point.

Answer (score 4):

Use iterator-based operations:

```
vec.reserve(vec.size() * 2);
vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to `reserve` before inserting? The complexity of `insert` must be `linear in the number of elements inserted plus the distance to the end of the vector`. If I understand correctly, this means that an implementation of `insert` is required to compute the distance between the two input iterators, and reserve enough capacity for the new number of elements, am I wrong?

Comment: @Luc But that invalidates the iterator range that you pass to it.

Comment: Hmm, right, I guess the requirement deals with amortized complexity then. Nevertheless, am I right in thinking that some implementations would specialize `insert` for random access iterators, in order to perform the reservation beforehand (even though the standard requires nothing of the sort)?

Comment: @Luc Almost definitely. I know that the stdlibc++ implementation does it for container *constructors*, it would be weird if `insert` behaved differently. And I expect other implementations of the standard library to also do this.

Comment: You should not not append this way, it is undefined behavior ([I made the same mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14791984/237483)).

Answer (score 1):

You should read the value of aVec.size() once *before* you start adding elements to aVec.