# Nice way to append a vector to itself

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector

I want to duplicate the contents of the vector and want them to be appended at the end of the original vector i.e. `v[i]=v[i+n] for i=0,2,...,n-1`

I am looking for a nice way to do it, not with a loop. I saw `std::vector::insert` but the iterative version forbids a iterator to `*this`(i.e behaviour is undefined).

I also tried `std::copy` as follows(but it resulted in segmentation fault):

`copy( xx.begin(), xx.end(), xx.end());`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong results when appending vector to itself using copy and back\_inserter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511510/wrong-results-when-appending-vector-to-itself-using-copy-and-back-inserter)

Comment: @BenVoigt, To be fair, when asking that question, I tried it and wanted to know why it didn't work. I didn't actually need an elegant working solution, so there are only mentions of any in the comments.

Comment: I have to wonder if most people would have got the implementation right the first time if they coded it with a loop.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Wow.  So many answers that are close, none with all the right pieces.  You need both `resize` (or `reserve`) and `copy_n`, along with remembering the original size.

```
auto old_count = xx.size();
xx.resize(2 * old_count);
std::copy_n(xx.begin(), old_count, xx.begin() + old_count);
```

or

```
auto old_count = xx.size();
xx.reserve(2 * old_count);
std::copy_n(xx.begin(), old_count, std::back_inserter(xx));
```

When using `reserve`, `copy_n` is required because the `end()` iterator points one element past the end... which means it also is not "before the insertion point" of the first insertion, and becomes invalid.

---

23.3.6.5 `[vector.modifiers]` promises that for `insert` and `push_back`:

> *Remarks:* Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. **If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.** If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of T or by any InputIterator operation there are no effects. If an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a non-CopyInsertable T, the eﬀects are unspecified.

Comment: The first version generates a memset on both g++ and clang (plus a memmove). The second version can be optimized to a memmove. https://godbolt.org/z/U2dafw

Comment: Looks to me as if the first version requires an accessible default constructor for the resize, while the second requires only a copy constructor.

Comment: For the next one wondering, as I did: In addition to the different iterators, in the first example `vector::resize` is used, while in in the example `vector::reserve` is used.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    {
        std::vector<int> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
        std::swap(v1, v2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I added a slightly more efficient version.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    {
        typedef std::move_iterator<decltype(v1)::iterator> VecMoveIter;
        std::vector<int> v2(v1);
        std::copy(VecMoveIter(v1.begin()), VecMoveIter(v1.end()), std::back_inserter(v2));
        v1 = std::move(v2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot about the existence of a copy-constructor and `std::vector::insert` :)

Comment: Not a bad thought, because the vector contents probably will get copied to a new location anyway.  But you're adding an extra copy.  Try constructing the new vector with the right capacity up front.

Comment: Also, it would be good to copy once and move the existing items instead of making two new copies of each.

Comment: Well if I do the allocation upfront I might as well delete my answer because then it becomes yours. But I agree on the move part of things. Besides the question is about a "nice way" not "the most efficient way" and I find my answer to be quite a clean and simple way of doing it.

Comment: @Borgleader: That wasn't where I meant to use move...  I think there's a `std::move_iterator` adaptor you can use with the `std::copy`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh wow, TIL the existed. Thanks! (edited my answer in case anyone stumbles on to this question).

Answer (score 0):

For appending more than one slot of duplicates.

```
    int main() {
        std::vector<int> V;
        V.push_back(1);
        V.push_back(2);

        int oldSize = V.size();
        int newSize = oldSize;
        int nDupSlot = 4;

        V.resize(nDupSlot * oldSize);
        for(int i=0; i<(nDupSlot-1); ++i) {
            std::copy_n(V.begin(), oldSize, V.begin() + newSize);       
            newSize = newSize + oldSize;
         }

        for(int i =0; i<V.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout<<V[i];
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
12121212
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most effective way, but it sure is simple:

```
std::vector<int> toAppend(xx);
xx.insert(xx.end(), toAppend.begin(), toAppend.end();
```