# Repeat elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector

```
vector<int>v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I'd like to repeat the elements in the vector for, say, 3 times, such that the vector becoms

```
v = {1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5};
```

**EDIT**: In fact, if I need to repeat the elements for many times, say 1000, obviously I have to come with something quick and light?

How do I do it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be tricky. If you want to avoid creating a temporary working object you have to be careful to avoid invalidating iterators as you go. This should do it:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// to avoid invalidating iterators, preallocate the memory
v.reserve(v.size() * 3);

// remember the end of the range to be duplicated
// (this is the iterator we don't want to invalidate)
auto end = std::end(v);

// insert two duplicates
v.insert(std::end(v), std::begin(v), end);
v.insert(std::end(v), std::begin(v), end);

for(auto i: v)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
```

More generally you could modify this to add multiple duplicates like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

std::size_t const no_of_duplicates = 1000;

// to avoid invalidating iterators, preallocate the memory
v.reserve(v.size() * no_of_duplicates);

// remember the end of the range to be duplicated
// (this is the iterator we don't want to invalidate)
auto end = std::end(v);

// insert duplicates (start from one because already have the first)
for(std::size_t i = 1; i < no_of_duplicates; ++i)
    v.insert(std::end(v), std::begin(v), end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `insert` method of vector class

```
v.insert(v.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: With `v.reserve(3 * v.size());` beforehand (iterator invalidation). And you have to remember the old end if you want to do it twice.

Comment: Seems it only repeats the elements twice?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::copy`

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> r;

for (auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(r));
}
v.swap(r);
```

Comment: More on [Nice way to append a vector to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636690/nice-way-to-append-a-vector-to-itself)