# Appending std::vector to itself, undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14781264/237483) made me uncertain about appending a vector to itself. So the question is: Following lines of code do what I expect, but is it standard conform?

```
vec.reserve(vec.size() * 2):
vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Following (without `reserve()`) still works, is it even standard conform?

```
vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Or implementation depending?

Comment: changing the content of a container(such as `std::vector`) while iterating through it is UB

Comment: For the conformant way, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17636690/103167

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the C++03 ISO spec (§23.1.1, Table 67) (and as @AndyProwl has mentioned, in §23.2.3, table 11 of the C++11 ISO spec), as part of sequence requirements, the operation `a.insert(p, i, j)` in a sequence container has this precondition:

> `i`, `j` are not iterators into `a`.

In other words, sequence containers are allowed to safely assume that if you do a range insertion operation, that range will not be defined from iterators over that original container.

As a result, if you try to insert a container's elements into itself, you are calling a standard library function and breaking a precondition.  This results in undefined behavior, meaning that it *might* work on some platforms if the library implementers are nice people, but it could terribly and catastrophically fail with no justification.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AndyProwl- Thanks!  Out of curiosity, is there an easy way to get a legal copy of that ISO spec?

Comment: @templatedtypdef: Yes, but you have to pay for it. Or you can get a draft for free from [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf).

Comment: @AndyProwl: That's a very recent draft, with substantial post-C++11 changes. N3337 is much more like the actual C++11 standard, with only minor editorial changes.

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot, thanks for the standard reference and the explaining words! I was so sure that the `resize()` example is correct, ouch.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thank you for the information. Where can I find a link to that draft?