# add at beginning and end of vector

Tags: c++, vector

Which is the smartest way to add at the beggining of a vector the last two elements of the vector itself and add at the end of the vetor the first two element of the vector?
I mean, if my starting vector is

```
v = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I need that it becames

```
v = 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
```

Comment: Is `vector::insert()` not sufficient for you?

Comment: Do you want to want to achieve something like periodic boundaries? If you are, you'd better go with applying the modulus operator on the index.

Comment: @Markus yes, but than i need to MPI_Send this vector and i think this is the easier way to continue my code

Comment: I've no idea what MPI_Send is, but you might end in a pitfall, because modifying one value will not synchronize the other values.

Comment: @Markus MPI is used for parallel computing, however I don't need to modify the values of the vector

Comment: Just keep in mind that these entries stay completely independent.

Comment: Don't worry! Insted are you shure that your answer is correct? I mean, there was another answer before in which it was said that I need to use reserve before to avoid a problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if the container is going to be large then consider using `deque` instead of `vector`. It's more efficient for adding at the start.

For `vector` you can't insert elements out of the `vector` to the start because the first thing that happens is everything in the vector gets moved (and all iterators and references to those elements are invalidated). So you either need to copy the elements out of the vector or you need to put insert elements at the start and then copy-assign to them. Assuming the type is `int`, I'll go with the former:

```
if (v.size() >= 2) {
    int tmp[] = {*(v.end() - 2), *(v.end() - 1)};
    v.insert(v.begin(), tmp, tmp + 2);
    tmp[0] = v[2]; tmp[1] = v[3];
    v.insert(v.end(), tmp, tmp + 2);
}
```

Alternatively, this uses more memory but might be easier to read. As a bonus it gives the strong exception guarantee even with types whose copy constructor can throw. My code above can be made to offer the strong guarantee by adding a call to `reserve`, but only because `int` is a trivial type:

```
if (v.size() >= 2) {
    std::vector<int> new_v;
    new_v.reserve(v.size() + 4);
    new_v.insert(new_v.end(), v.end() - 2, v.end());
    new_v.insert(new_v.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
    new_v.insert(new_v.end(), v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
    v.swap(new_v);
}
```

For `deque` you don't need to store any elements outside the container provided you use a reference instead of an iterator to access them. Again this only offers the basic exception guarantee.

```
if (v.size() >= 2) {
    v.push_front(v.back());
    v.push_front(*&(v.end() - 1));
    v.push_back(*&(v.begin() + 2));
    v.push_back(*&(v.begin() + 3));
}
```

Comment: Can you safely insert a range of iterators from a vector into itself? I thought that was UB.

Comment: @SteveJessop your code doesn't work as I want, the output is `6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2` without the added line in the `vector` part works. I necessary need that line?

Comment: @SteveJessop thank you for your help, however I need to use vector and your code dosen't works with the `reserve` line

Comment: @SteveJessop Now it works, is this the easier way? Can you explain me why Marcus's answer is wrong?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think even at the end it's UB, because if the vector needs to resize, those iterators would be invalidated.

Comment: @Wellen: Markus's answer is wrong in two ways. The first way (which I got wrong too in the first version of my answer) is that calling `insert` might reallocate the vector, and if it does it invalidates all iterators. So by the time it tries to copy from them they may not longer be usable because the vector has moved to a different location. The second wrong thing (that I managed to get right), is that his second lines copies the last two elements of the vector to the start -- but those last two elements are the two that were copied from the start, not the original last two.

Comment: @MooingDuck: true, but one of the incorrect versions of my answer had a `reserve()` in it. Since it's no longer needed I've now removed it...

Comment: @Wellen: oh, and a further mistake that Markus and I both made, is that even if the vector doesn't reallocate it still invalidates all iterators and references after the insertion point. The `reserve()` I had prevents reallocation but of course doesn't prevent this problem. So you can't insert elements from the end at the beginning no matter what.

Comment: Tbh it's a miracle I got out of the mess I put myself in, without any downvotes.

Comment: Any insertion, anywhere, invalidates the `end()` iterator.  Even if no reallocation is needed.  Is there an `insert_n` like `copy_n`?  If not, perhaps use `copy_n` with `back_inserter`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I thought about `back_inserter`, decided that it didn't help the readability of any of my insertions to turn them into `copy`. But there's not a huge amount in it.

Answer (score 2):

My five cents

```
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    v.insert( v.end(), { v[0], v[1], v[v.size() - 2], v[v.size() - 1] } );
    std::rotate( v.begin(), std::prev( v.end(), 2 ), v.end() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: rotate isn't intuitive here, but it sure works well!

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow does your code work with c++? or only with c++11?

Comment: @ Mooing Duck I wanted to show something original.:)

Comment: @Wellen: This uses C++11

Comment: @Wellen I use std::initoalizer_list that was introduced in C++ 11.

Comment: I can't use c++11, I'm sorry

Comment: You can more-or-less do this in C++03, but explicitly copy the values to an array (like in my answer, but 4 elements instead of 2). The initializer list is is nicer though because it never has to mention the `value_type` of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>By using the vector::insert function for ranges. It is easier to first insert the first two elements at the end.</strike>

```
v.insert(v.end(), v.begin(), v.begin()+2);
v.insert(v.begin(), v.end()-2, v.end());
```

Edit:
Is undefined behaviour.

[Appending std::vector to itself, undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14792174/2056153)

Comment: undefined behavior, the iterators may be invalidated before they're read from

Comment: I actually thought of that and therfore read the vector::insert reference at cplusplus.com. I did'nt find a hint, that it is UB. But you are acutually right it is Undefined Behaviour! [Discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14792174/2056153) If the source iterators belong to the target container, you are breaking a precondition.