# Is it safe to append std::string to itself?

Tags: c++, stl

Considering a code like this:

```
std::string str = "abcdef";
const size_t num = 50;

const size_t baselen = str.length();
while (str.length() < num)
    str.append(str, 0, baselen);
```

Is it safe to call `std::basic_string<T>::append()` on itself like this? Cannot the source memory get invalidated by enlarging before the copy operation?

I could not find anything in the standard specific to that method. It says the above is equivalent to `str.append(str.data(), baselen)`, which I think might not be entirely safe unless there is another detection of such cases inside `append(const char*, size_t)`.

I checked a few implementations and they seemed safe one way or another, but my question is if this behavior is guaranteed. E.g. "[Appending std::vector to itself, undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791984/appending-stdvector-to-itself-undefined-behavior)" says it's not for `std::vector`.

Comment: It should be but like yourself I can't find anything one way or the other.  `str += str;` is legal and it boils down to the same thing so I guess it is fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Actually, there's a good reason for not making it illegal. With strings, attaching the same string to itself, or a subset of the string, is reasonable. With `vector`, it's a lot less likely.

Comment: @NicolBolas I get that.  I just wasn't finding the standardies to support my argument.  Looks like Rakete1111 did.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to §21.4.6.2/§21.4.6.3:

> The function  [*`basic_string& append(const charT* s, size_type n);`*] replaces the string controlled by *this with a string of length size() + n whose first size() elements are a copy of the original string controlled by *this and whose remaining elements are a copy of the initial n elements of s.

*Note: This applies to every `append` call, as every `append` can be implemented in terms of `append(const charT*, size_type)`, as defined by the standard (§21.4.6.2/§21.4.6.3).*

So basically, `append` makes a copy of `str` (let's call the copy `strtemp`), appends `n` characters of `str2` to `strtemp`, and then replaces `str` with `strtemp`.

For the case that `str2` is `str`, nothing changes, as the string is enlarged when the temporary copy is assigned, not before.

Even though it is not explicitly stated in the standard, it is guaranteed (if the implementation is exactly as stated in the standard) by the definition of `std::basic_string<T>::append`.

Thus, this is not undefined behavior.

Comment: I see, thanks - I should have read that definition of `append(const charT*, size_type)` more literally.

Answer (score 6):

This is complicated.

One thing that can be said for certain. If you use iterators:

```
std::string str = "abcdef";
str.append(str.begin(), str.end());
```

then you are *guaranteed* to be safe. Yes, really. Why? Because the specification states that the behavior of the iterator functions is equivalent to calling `append(basic_string(first, last))`. That obviously creates a temporary copy of the string. So if you need to insert a string into itself, you're guaranteed to be able to do it with the iterator form.

Granted, implementations don't have to actually copy it. But they do need to respect the standard specified behavior. An implementation could choose to make a copy only if the iterator range is inside of itself, but the implementation would still have to check.

All of the other forms of `append` are defined to be equivalent to calling `append(const charT *s, size_t len)`. That is, your call to append above is equivalent to you doing `append(str.data(), str.size())`. So what does the standard say about what happens if `s` is inside of `*this`?

Nothing at all.

The only requirement of `s` is:

> `s` points to an array of at least `n` elements of `charT`.

Since it does not *expressly* forbid `s` pointing into `*this`, then it must be allowed. It would also be exceedingly strange if the iterator version allows self-assignment, but the pointer&size version did not.