# Extend a string with another string within the same vector Rust

Tags: string, vector, rust

I am new to Rust and I cannot solve this simple problem:
Consider following code:

```
let mut a = vec![String::from("aa"), String::from("bb")];
a[0] += &*a[1];
```

Borrow checker rightfully complains about me having both immutable and mutable borrows here. It also suggests me:

```
help: try adding a local storing this...
  --> src\main.rs:61:15
   |
61 |     a[0] += &*a[1];
   |               ^^^^
help: ...and then using that local here
  --> src\main.rs:61:5
   |
61 |     a[0] += &*a[1];
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I do not really understand what that means. Do I really need to clone the string to perform such an easy operation? (That would result in 2 overall copies: into temporary and then back into a[0], instead of optimal 1 copy straight into a[0])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naively, like this (no reason to dereference `a[1]`):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![String::from("aa"), String::from("bb")];
    a[0] += &a[1];
}
```

Sadly, as you noticed, this creates a problem with the borrow checker. Modifying `a[0]` borrows it mutably, while you also need to borrow `a[1]` immutably to append it. And borrowing `a` both mutably and immutably at the same time isn't allowed:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:14
  |
3 |     a[0] += &a[1];
  |     ---------^---
  |     |        |
  |     |        immutable borrow occurs here
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
  |     mutable borrow later used here
```

The reason is that Rust doesn't know that `a[0]` and `a[1]` are independent variables. This behavior is intentional and important, as it prevents some cases that could lead to undefined behavior. Rust has a zero-undefined-behavior guarantee.

You can split the array into two independently mutable parts via the `split_at_mut` function, though. This works because Rust can now guarantee that both parts are independent. Borrowing them sequentially makes it impossible for (current) Rust to prove that.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![String::from("aa"), String::from("bb")];

    let (a_left, a_right) = a.split_at_mut(1);
    a_left[0] += &a_right[0];

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

```
["aabb", "bb"]
```

Note that the `split_at_mut` is almost free. It doesn't actually copy anything, it just creates two slices that point at two non-overlapping parts of the array. It doesn't cause any performance overhead.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about that hack. But, reducing to even simpler case, you can not have:
`let mut a: String = "11".to_string();

 a += &a;`?

Comment: Also this becomes harder (if case required) when it is i and j instead of 0 and 1, is there any better way to do that?

Comment: @nexus.chebykin *"is there any better way to do that?"* - You could use `RefCell` for interior mutability; but that would introduce a runtime overhead.

Comment: *"did not know about that hack"* - I don't think it's a hack. I think it's the intended way of borrowing exclusively from multiple places of the vector at once. *"when it is i and j instead of 0 and 1"* - Just use the proper offset in your `split_at_mut`. You can split at any position.

Comment: "`let mut a: String = "11".to_string();   a += &a;`" - this would be undefined behaviour in most programming languages. Rust is just the only language that complains about it; as I already mentioned, Rust by definition has zero undefined behaviour.

Comment: _"You can split at any position"_. Yes, no wonder. But it requires if checking whether i < j or i > j and looks ugly taking around 10 lines instead of 1...

Comment: _"This would be undefined behavior in most programming languages"_ For example? In C++ It is perfectly fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249939/discussion-between-nexus-chebykin-and-finomnis).

Comment: I think you are mistaken about C++ ... `std::string::append` and `std::string::operator+=` both create a temporary copy, and `strcat` explicitely forbids that the target overlaps with the source.

Comment: No, string.append does not create temporary

Comment: @nexus.chebykin https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075341/2902833
No, it doesn't create a temporary copy, but it still copies the original string instead of appending to it. Which is not how Rust behaves, Rust's `append` behave more like a combination of `strcat` combined with a reallocation in case the string grows larger than capacity.

Comment: Either way, you have to choose your evil. There are only two ways to concatenate a string: via performing one extra copy, which allows appending a string to itself (as in C++/Python/Java), or via modifying the original string in place (like in C or Rust), which doesn't allow appending a string to itself. This problem is closely related to why it isn't legal to modify an array whilst iterating over it, in case you ever stumbled across this.