# How to use c++11 move semantics to append vector contents to another vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider this snippet:

```
class X;

void MoveAppend(vector<X>& src, vector<X>& dst) {
   dst.reserve(dst.size() + src.size());
   for (const X& x : src) dst.push_back(x);
   src.clear();
}
```

If we assume that `class X` implements move semantics, how can I efficiently implement `MoveAppend`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just do:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

void MoveAppend(std::vector<X>& src, std::vector<X>& dst) 
{
    if (dst.empty())
    {
        dst = std::move(src);
    }
    else
    {
        dst.reserve(dst.size() + src.size());
        std::move(std::begin(src), std::end(src), std::back_inserter(dst));
        src.clear();
    }
}
```

If `dst` is empty, a move-assignment from `src` to `dst` will do the job - that will be as cheap as it can be, just "stealing" the array encapsulated by `src` so that `dst` will point to it afterwards.

If `dst` is not empty, elements appended to `dst` will be move-constructed from elements in `src`. After the call to [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move), `src` will not be empty - it will contain "zombie" moved-from elements. That's why the call to `clear()` is still necessary.

Comment: @ŁukaszLew: Is it guaranteed to not be empty?  If it can possibly be empty, it might be a good idea to check that first.  Then you can still do a simple move of the whole container, which will possibly be a lot cheaper.

Comment: can you explain why this is better than `dst.insert(end(dst), begin(src), end(src))`?

Comment: @TemplateRex: That would copy-construct the new elements of `dst` from the corresponding elements of `src`. What the OP wants is moving

Comment: But in practice, the ranged-insert avoid multiple `push_back()` and reallocation of capacity() calls, whereas the `std::back_inserter()` doesn't (unless preceded by a `reserve()`. So it's not clear if the move is even faster than the ranged-insert.

Comment: @TemplateRex: That entirely depends on the class being copied/moved. Also notice, that the call to `reserve()` is there.

Comment: It is possible to use `insert` in tandem with move iterators.

Comment: @TemplateRex `dst.insert(end(dst), make_move_iterator(begin(src)), make_move_iterator(end(src)));`.

Comment: Wouldn't the move still require copying elements in this case?

Comment: @user18348324 Moving is more efficient, if the items moved from one vector to the other vector contain internal state. Think for example of a vector of long strings, where moving just requires to move the pointers to the string contents and the length and allocation counters, while copying requires to copy all the contents of all the strings, too!

Answer (score 23):

I would slightly prefer this to the accepted answer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator append(const std::vector<T>& src, std::vector<T>& dest)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator result;

    if (dest.empty()) {
        dest = src;
        result = std::begin(dest);
    } else {
        result = dest.insert(std::end(dest), std::cbegin(src), std::cend(src));
    }

    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator append(std::vector<T>&& src, std::vector<T>& dest)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator result;

    if (dest.empty()) {
        dest = std::move(src);
        result = std::begin(dest);
    } else {
        result = dest.insert(std::end(dest),
                             std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(src)),
                             std::make_move_iterator(std::end(src)));
    }

    src.clear();
    src.shrink_to_fit();

    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<std::string> v1 {"world", "!"};

    std::vector<std::string> v2 {" "}, v3 {"hello"}, v4 {};

    append(v1, v2); // copies
    append(std::move(v2), v3); // moves
    append(std::move(v3), v4); // moves

    std::copy(std::cbegin(v4), std::cend(v4), std::ostream_iterator<std::string> {std::cout});
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a much better answer, has overloads for lvalue and rvalue source, and uses std::vector::insert().

Comment: Why do you "clean" the rvalue source? I think that is doing unsolicited extra work.

Comment: @dats It's an interesting point - my view is that the caller would expect the capacity of the rvalue source to be zero after the call, which would not be the case otherwise.

Comment: @Daniel caller shouldn't expect anything about the state of moved object. moved object is considered invalidated and should not be used in any way.

Comment: there shouldn't be 2 versions of this function. The source should be passed by value, not by const ref or by rvalue. If you pass the source by value, the caller can decide wether to move or copy.

Comment: @grisevg: Still, it's neighbourly. Same as how VS in debug fills uninitialised memory (whose contents are technically unspecified and unreliable) with things like `0xDEADBEEF`, to be helpful to programmers doing debugging. In this case it's relatively little extra work even for release... though I concede it may be more than we'd like because it's still _N_ destructor calls.

Comment: Can this be reduced using perfect forwarding?

Comment: Should the dst argument not precede the src argument? Granted the OP supplied the argument order. Or am I hallucinating a standard convention that does not exist? My feeling: it's an analogue of +=, so dst should precede src in the argument list.

Answer (score 6):

Just trying to improve slightly the answer of @Daniel: the function should not be defined twice, the source should be passed by value.

```
// std::vector<T>&& src - src MUST be an rvalue reference
// std::vector<T> src - src MUST NOT, but MAY be an rvalue reference
template <typename T>
inline void append(std::vector<T> source, std::vector<T>& destination)
{
    if (destination.empty())
        destination = std::move(source);
    else
        destination.insert(std::end(destination),
                   std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(source)),
                   std::make_move_iterator(std::end(source)));
}
```

Now the caller can decide whether to copy or move.

```
std::vector<int> source {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> destination {0};
auto v1 = append<int>(source,destination); // copied once
auto v2 = append<int>(std::move(source),destination); // copied 0 times!!
```

Never use `&&` for arguments, unless you have to (for example: std::ifstream&&).

Comment: `destiny` is an interesting pick of name!

Comment: I quite liked it!

Comment: In this case there are two vector memory allocations: one to copy `source` and a second to extend the size of `destination`. If we specialize `append` function on `const&` and `&&` (as in Daniel's answer) then we only do one vector memory allocation, to extend the size of `destination`

Comment: @William No, not having && doesn't mean the lvalue source cannot be a reference to an rvalue. When I move the source, there is no memory allocation.

Comment: @MFnx If the caller does not move in (`append(src, dst)`), taking by value will guarantee two vector allocations: one to copy from the caller into our by-value argument, and a second to extend the size of the destination vector (which then has its content populated by moving from the `source` vector). If the caller does move in (`append(move(src), dst)`), then there is only one allocation: extending the size of destination.

Comment: @William Exactly. So the caller can decide wether or not to copy (or wether or not to keep the original source). Elegant, and only 1 function is needed.

Comment: @MFnx what I've been trying to say is that in the case the caller wants to copy, having the function take the vector by value means 2 vector allocations, whereas taking the vector by const& means only 1 vector allocation. Hope this is clear now :)

Comment: I voted this answer up because it's elegant and answers the original question about moving the vector contents.  But @William has a point, that the "copy" scenario results in allocating a temporary vector on the stack (whose elements are then moved by the function), whereas the pass-by-reference function allows it to copy the elements straight from the source.  Therefore, when copying to a non-empty destination, this will use an extra allocation for that temporary vector (not the elements, just the container).

Comment: Yes, there is that extra allocation, I had overseen that. Thanks for pointing that out. I wonder however if the compiler could optimize this (I'll have to look into it).

Comment: @mfnx: Compilers are rather naive about heap operations. Their optimizers don't "see", that allocating that space on the heap, then copying the vector contents to it, then moving from the copy, then deallocating the space on the heap again can be replaced by a direct copy from the original.

Comment: The comment `// copied once` in the answer is misleading. It should read: `// copied once, but to the wrong place, and then moved again`.

Comment: Could somebdy please vote this answer out of existence. Or delete it, since it's deeply and fundamentally wrong.