# C++ pushing elements of a vector of vectors into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm just wondering whether there is a simple, quick way to insert the elements of a vector of vectors inside a vector.

For example:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<double> > vals
{

    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
};
std::vector<double> myvector;
```

so `myvector` would then contain: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

I've tried using `insert` and `push_back` but had no luck.

Edit:

I have used:

`myvector.insert(vals.begin(), vals.end());` - No matching member function to call to 'insert'

Comment: Please show the exact code you used.

Comment: One would think that two normal [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) would be all it takes.

Comment: I think you mean that you want the elements of the vectors _inside_ the vector-of-vectors to be inserted into the other vector, correct? Please re-word if so.

Comment: @davmac Yes, but, I would like them to be inserted into a just a `vector` I do not need another `std::vector<vector<double> >`

Comment: Right, then you need to clarify that in the question. You say 'insert the elements of a vector of vectors' but those would be vectors. You mean the elements _inside_ those vectors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
// c++11
for(auto && v : vals){
  myvector.insert(myvector.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
}

// non c++11
for(std::vector<std::vector<double> >::const_iterator it = vals.begin(), end = vals.end(); it != end; ++it){
  myvector.insert(myvector.end(), it->begin(), it->end());
}
```

Comment: A normal reference for first would be quite enough.

Comment: @RedX - `no matching member function for call to 'insert'` Any ideas why?

Comment: a simple optimization here, would be to resize myvector first. This prevents unnecessary reallocations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I remember reading somewhere that if the compiler thinks that a reference is enough here, with `&&` it will use that anyway. If it thinks that moving is also good, it might use that then. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: the inner loop shoud be myvector.insert(myvector.end(), v.begin(), v.end())<

Comment: @Enigma You would have to iterate over all vectors anyway to find out if they are the same length anyway. I'm unsure if `insert` would not do a `std::difference` anyway if the iterators allows it and preallocate.

Comment: Also, you can't use `vals::const_iterator`, you need to use the complete type instead of the variable for scope.

Comment: @RedX: Yes but it potentially does a reallocate every vector

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, was just too lazy to type it out. Fixed it now.

Comment: `auto&&` does not move. You're just binding a reference to an object.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your vector of vectors is built in the first place, there may be a more efficient way to approach this.

If your sub-vectors are all the same length (as appears to be the case from the code example), then the best thing may be to view myvector as a 2D array and build directly into this buffer.

If the sub-vector lengths can vary, but the code that builds your vector of vectors *only ever actually adds stuff at the end*, then you can use something like [the 'collapsed vector vector' class I describe here](http://upcoder.com/2/efficient-vectors-of-vectors/) to build this data, instead of a vector of vectors.
(And after that, again, your data is already in the kind of contiguous buffer you are looking for.)

Either way, *if performance or memory footprint are important here* then avoiding the vector of vector construct can eliminate a lot of buffer manipulation overhead, and work out as quite a significant optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert all of the elements of `vals` into a single vector:

**Brute Force Method**

```
for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < vals[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        myvector.push_back(vals[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**More Elegant Method**

```
struct AddVector
{
    std::vector<double> myvector;
    void operator()(const std::vector<int>& a)
    {
        std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(myvector));
    }
};

// somewhere in your code
AddVector av;
std::for_each(vals.begin(), vals.end(), av);
myvector.swap(av.myvector);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `vals` is a vector of vectors, but `myvector` is a vector of doubles. Trying to insert from the first into the second will not work as the contained types are different (`std::vector<double>` versus `double`).

Instead you have to manually insert from each sub-vector of `vals` into `myvector`.

Answer (score 0):

resize myvector to the size of the sum of the sizes of the vectors in vals. For every vector in vals concat it to myvector. To get a idea how to concat:

[Concatenating two std::vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stl-vectors)