# Why does std::vector not have an append method?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

The recommendation for appending one vector to another (according to [Concatenating two std::vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stdvectors)) is to use:

```
vector1.insert( vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector2.end() );
```

Why does vector not have a method along the lines of:

```
vector1.append(vector2);
```

The only reason that comes to mind is that it may be unclear exactly what append does.

Comment: Why do you need another way of doing something you can already do?

Comment: There isn't a technical reason why it doesn't exist. It's a question of rather you want a fully featured (some would say bloated) interface or a short and concise (some would say incomplete) interface. It's a matter of preference.

Comment: probably because `append` would just be a special case of `insert`. `insert` can do much more than put something at the end of something.

Comment: Because, basically, STL traffics in **ranges** rather than containers. Containers are a convenient way of managing ranges, but ranges are fundamental. `insert` takes a range, which is far more general than having a function that takes its own container type. If `vector` had `append(const vector&)`, what would the appropriate signature be for `list::append? Should it take a `vector` or a `list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty good reason. In fact, as an apt example, I think you've got the meaning of "append" wrong. I'd expect it to be equivalent to `push_back` (which exists), whereas you're looking for something more like "concatenate".

Why isn't there a `concatenate` function? Well, there could have been. But the standard doesn't like to give you things you don't really need, and (as you've shown) this operation is pretty easy to implement yourself.

Comment: This same argument could be applied for any method besides `insert`, `erase`, `begin` and `end`. All of `vector` besides these methods is trivial to implement, still `push_back` and `size` are provided, because you don't want to reimplement commonly used, trivial stuff (possibly with different names) in each and every project.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Suggest it to the committee then. But I don't see how this is answerable beyond what I've posed.