# recursion on returning vectors c++

Tags: javascript, c++, recursion, vector

Hey guys I am trying trying to right this javascript code into c++. I am doing quick sort and everything is straight forward minus the last step.

```
function quickSort(arr)
{
    //base case if the arr is 1 or 0 then return the array
    if(arr.length === 1 || arr.length === 0)
    {
        return arr;
    }


    var pivotIndex = Math.floor(arr.length/2);
    var pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];

    var before = [];
    var after = [];

    for(var counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++)
    {
        if(counter === pivotIndex)
            continue;
        if(pivotValue <= arr[counter])
        {
            before.push(arr[counter])
        }
        else
        {
            after.push(arr[counter])
        }
    }
//this step I am having trouble rewriting in c++
    return quickSort(after).concat(pivotValue).concat(quickSort(before));

}
```

I am having a hard time rewriting the recursive step in c++. I am not sure how concat 2 vector. I tried using the insert method but I keep getting an error about invalid use of void expression.

```
vector<int> quickSort(vector<int> arr)
{
    if(arr.size() == 1 || arr.size()  == 0)
    {
        return  arr;
    }

    int pivotIndex = arr.size()/2;
    int pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];

    vector<int> before;
    vector<int> after;


    //put values in before or after the piv
    for(size_t counter = 0; counter < arr.size(); counter++)
    {
        if(counter == pivotIndex)
            continue;
        if(pivotValue <= arr[counter])
            before.push_back( arr[counter]);
        else
            after.push_back( arr[counter]);
    }

   return //????? not sure how to do this

}
```

Comment: Use more than one line?

Comment: lol sure thats great I understand that but my c++ is a bit rusty so an example would be nice

Comment: Concatenate `v` and `v2`: `v.insert(v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end())`.

Comment: It would be more performant to make the partition in place to avoid extra allocations (and so working with *range* instead of *container*).

Comment: And except if it is for exercise, we have `std::sort`.

Comment: Step 1: rewrite JS into doing one line per "thing".  Step 2: test new code works the same as old code.  Step 3: Try to rewite each line of JS in C++.  None of these involve "invalid use of a void expression", and you shoukd have *something* besides ??? before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you realized that your core question was "how to concatenate two `vector`s", and you found a [right answer: using `insert`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201729/5767783). Now your question is about why you were getting "an error about invalid use of void expression." (That's the assumption my answer is for, at least.)

That's because you were likely trying to do something like the following:

```
return quickSort(after).insert( /* stuff */ );
```

**which is wrong.** In JavaScript, `array.concat` *returns* the concatenated array. It's return type is effectively `Array`, and so doing `return arr.concat(arr2)` returns an `Array` because `arr.concat` would return an `Array`. Further, in JavaScript, `array.concat` doesn't modify the array it was called on, but rather returns a new array.

*In C++, however,* [`vector.insert` (#4 in the reference) returns `void`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). That means it returns nothing. So when you try to return the result of `insert`, you get that error about invalid use of a void expression. Further, in C++, `vector.insert` *does* modify the `vector` it was called on.

So how do you use insert in this case?

```
vector<int> quickSort(vector<int> arr)
{
    // ...

    // Sort `before` and `after`
    before = quickSort(before);
    after = quickSort(after);

    // Modify `after` and return it.
    after.push_back(pivotValue);
    after.insert(after.end(), before.begin(), before.end());
    return after;
}
```

**Note:** My code isn't optimal and the idea of rewriting JS in C++ is also oddly specific. My answer is to simply outline the problem asked in the question, **not to give a good C++ implementation of quick sort**.

Answer (score 0):

To concat two vector , you can use std::merge
like:`std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(dst));`