# C++: Insert vector into anonymous vector, recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

My goal is to generate vector with pattern {1} given max_=2, {1,2,1} given max_=3, {1,2,1,3,1,2,1} given max_=4... etc

Here is my psuedocode:

```
std::vector<int> generate_zimin(int max_)
{
    if(max_ == 2)
    {
        return {1};
    }
    else
    {
        return {generate_zimin(max_-1), (max_-1), generate_zimin(max_-1)};
    }
}
```

How do I insert vectors into an anonymous vector?

edit:

```
std::vector<int> generate_zimin(std::vector<int> current, int max_)
{
    if(max_ == 2)
    {
        return {1};
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<int> prev = generate_zimin(current, max_-1);
        current.insert(current.end(), std::begin(prev), std::end(prev));
        current.push_back(max_-1);
        current.insert(current.end(), std::begin(prev), std::end(prev));
        return current;
    }
}
```

looks a lot less elegant, and I was just trying to avoid that, but I can see
why I was wrong.

Comment: You don't. Why does it have to be "anonymous"? What's wrong with using a local variable to accumulate the result?

Comment: There isn't really a way to do it in a one-liner. See this question about concatenating vectors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stdvectors

Comment: @IgorTandetnik By using local variable, I should declare an empty vector at the start of the function, and append generate_zimin(max_-1) to it, then push_back max_-1 to it, then append generate_zimin(max_z-1), then return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is there no syntax for this,  it is a bad idea for performance.  You'll be allocating and deallocating vectors on every function call.  You should create a single vector at the beginning and use it in all the calls.  This could improve performance by a factor of 100.

You can even calculate the total size of the vector at the beginning and `reserve()` the needed capacity.

Comment: How would I reserve the needed capacity when its function is also recursive? A generate_zimin(n)'s total space = 2*generate_zimin(n-1)'s total space +1. I must be overthinking this too much

Comment: Total capacities are 1, 3, 7, 15, 31.  Punch that into a search and voila: https://oeis.org/A000225 - it is `2^n - 1`.