# Equivalent of python list multiplying with a scale in c++

Tags: python, c++

How would you code list multiplying with a scale in c++?

In python I would do:

```
lst = [1,2,3]
lst*3 # we will get [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

What is the c++ equivalent of that?

Comment: There's nothing built-in. But you can use vector concatenation repeatedly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stdvectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the operation of multiplication, for example, you are developing some math library, you can consider the [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). Otherwise, I suggest you throwing the python style away while working with C++, just use `std::copy` or `vector::insert` with a loop to insert repeated elements into a vector.

```
std::vector<int>& operator*(std::vector<int>& vec, std::size_t n) {
    auto initSize = vec.size();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        vec.insert(vec.end(), vec.begin() + initSize * i, vec.end());
    }
    return vec;
}

// commutative principle for multiplication
std::vector<int>& operator*(std::size_t n, std::vector<int>& vec) {
    return operator*(vec, n);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};
    vec = vec * 3; // 3 * vec is OK too

    for (auto val : vec) {
        std::cout << val << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd really discourage this as it is not clear what `vec * 3` means to an average programmer. My first guess would be element-wise vector multiplication. Doing this causes much ambiguity. A much better option is to just create a named function instead and call it: `vec = repeat(vec, 3)`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I agree with you.

Comment: It’s just not that common. If you find it common, write a function that takes a sequence and appends n times. (There may be a C++20 ranges one-liner…)

Comment: @Ben C++ committee has all kinds of experts with very different background, it's kind of hard to say "it's just not that common". With my technique background, I would say: we should totally remove the operator overloading from the C++ Standard.

Comment: Ok. I think the generic algorithm you may want is `template <typename Range, typename OutIter> OutIter copy_n_times(const Range&, OutIter out, std::size_t n) { OutIter result = out; for (std::size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) { result = std::copy(range.begin(); range.end(), result); } return result; }`