# Create const std::vector as the concatenation of two const std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, stl, constants, declaration

I would like to create a `const std::vector` to contain all the elements of two other `const std::vector` of the same type. Since the vector is `const` I can not concatenate it step by step with the two `const std::vector` using the method mentioned in [Concatenating two std::vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stdvectors).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> int_a{0,1};
    const std::vector<int> int_b{2,3};
    const std::vector<int> all_ints;
    
    for (int i: all_ints)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

For the example above I would like to define `all_ints` in a way that the output is `0 1 2 3`.

How could that be done?

Comment: did you try something? Are you struggling because of the `const` ? If thats the issue then use a non-const vector, fill it with values from the other two, then use that to initialize the const vector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating two std::vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201718/concatenating-two-stdvectors)

Comment: @AshrafulAlamShakil the elephant in the room is `const`. I am really not sure if OP doesnt know how to concatenate at all, or if it is only the `const` that creates the struggle.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about removing the `const`. I agree that would make it easier. I wanted this question to be specifically about the definition of a const vector though so I know that `int_a`, `int_b` and `total_ints` stay constant when I use them throughout my program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a function that takes the other two vectors, creates a third one, inserts  values from the first two, returns the result by value. Then assign this to your const vector:

```
const std::vector<int> int_a{0,1};
const std::vector<int> int_b{2,3};
const std::vector<int> all_ints = concat(int_a, int_b);
```

Comment: range-v3 provides such a function: https://godbolt.org/z/9WP68anx4. Its unsure if this functionality will even be available in c++23, so best not depend on this becoming part of the standard library soon.

Answer (score 3):

I actually don't know what's the essence of creation of const vectors like this. But a simple hack is to create a temporary non-const vector and fill it with the first two vectors, then create the final const vector. eg:

```
const std::vector<int> int_a{0,1};
const std::vector<int> int_b{2,3};
std::vector<int> middle(int_a);
middle.insert(middle.begin(),int_b.begin(),int_b.end());
const std::vector<int> all_ints(middle);
```

As suggested in comments, the last line could be written as:

```
const std::vector<int> all_ints = std::move(middle);
```

Comment: You can also move `middle` to avoid copying.

Comment: And you can also move this concatenation business into a lambda so the temporary doesn't have to stick around: https://godbolt.org/z/cbro6cx11

Comment: That's actually less readable (that's not the aim of lambda at the end).

Comment: This avoids having a redundant temporary sticking around. Of course the most optimal option is to create a free-standing concat function that you call with these vectors.

Comment: I think your own answer is actually quite good, but lambda in this case doesn't fit well.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in [*@Ayxan Haqverdili*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74375849/11455384), you can create a concatenation function that will be used to initialize your vector.

I propose the following implementation for such a function:

```
template <template <typename, typename> typename C, typename ... Args>
C<Args...> concat(const C<Args...> & lhs, const C<Args...> & rhs)
{
    C<Args...> res(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend());
    res.insert(res.cend(), rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    return res;
}
```

**Note:** This implementation is generalized to all [standard library sequence containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) except `std::array`.

Which can then be used like this:

```
const std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3};
const std::vector<int> b {4, 5};
    
const std::vector<int> ab = concat(a, b);
```

<sup>[*Live example here*](https://godbolt.org/z/PY7rvGnd9)</sup>

---

An alternative and simpler version could be:

```
template <typename C>
C concat(const C & lhs, const C & rhs)
{
    C res(lhs.size() + rhs.size());
    typename C::iterator it = std::copy(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(), res.begin());
    std::copy(rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend(), it);
    return res;
}
```

<sup>[*Live example here*](https://godbolt.org/z/dThvT487T)</sup>

Comment: Your template can be simplified to not use parameter packs https://godbolt.org/z/EKKo3zE3b

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Oh you're right, I overcomplicated things for no reason :o The only thing is the use of `reserve()` which is specific to `std::vector` (but since the question asks about `std::vector`, it's fair :) )

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I edited the question and added an alternative version based on your comments. Thanks for the observation :)

Comment: Note that your version value-initializes elements of `res` and then overwrites them with values from `lhs` and `rhs`. This requires the type to have an accessible default constructor, also introduces the initialization overhead. My version avoids both of these issues by using `reserve` + `insert` instead.

Comment: Yes indeed, actually I tried to avoid to use `reserve()` since I wanted to have it compatible with other sequence containers too. But it seems it has a cost one way or another XD

Comment: Otherwise there is no point of using a template if only one single type is eligible to be used.

Comment: There is always a way to avoid all unnecessary costs in the most generic way in C++ ;-) https://godbolt.org/z/r1TbYE1rv

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Ahah right, this should be what I should have come with XD Well done !

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another implementation that can also easily be modified to even modify the contents of `all_ints` at a future time. It does not require recent c++ versions.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> int_a{ 0,1 };
    const std::vector<int> int_b{ 2,3 };
    const std::vector<int> all_ints(int_a.size()+ int_b.size());
    std::vector<int>& all_intsr = const_cast<std::vector<int>&>(all_ints);
    std::copy(int_b.begin(), int_b.end(), std::copy(int_a.begin(), int_a.end(), all_intsr.begin()));
}
```

This takes advantage of a being able to legally cast a `const vector&` to a `vector` with the following restriction to prevent UB. One may not modify the vector object. This does not include the contents owned by the vector which is not const. Neither `begin()` or `end()` modify the vector object. Also modifying element of it later are legal such as this.

```
all_intsr[3]=42;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to iterate over both vectors, you can do it using a custom view concatenator.  The following is much more efficient than creating (and destroying) another container just to iterate over both ranges.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto concat_view(T1& lhs, T2& rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>);
    using T1_ = std::remove_reference_t<T1>;
    using T2_ = std::remove_reference_t<T2>;
    if constexpr (std::is_const_v<T1_> || std::is_const_v<T2_>)
    {
        using Iter = typename std::decay_t<T1>::const_iterator;
        return std::array<std::ranges::subrange<Iter>, 2>{std::as_const(lhs), std::as_const(rhs)} | std::views::join;
    }
    else
    {
        using Iter = typename std::decay_t<T1>::iterator;
        return std::array<std::ranges::subrange<Iter>, 2>{lhs, rhs} | std::views::join;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3}, v2{4,5,6};
    for (int& val : concat_view(v1, v2))
        ++val;
    for (const auto& val : concat_view(std::as_const(v1), v2))
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note: range-v3 is preferred to this implementation